# Greatest Common Divisor

Tags: code-golf, math, arithmetic, number-theory

Your task is to compute the [greatest common divisor (GCD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) of two given integers in as few bytes of code as possible.

You may write a program or function, taking input and returning output [via any of our accepted standard methods](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) (including STDIN/STDOUT, function parameters/return values, command-line arguments, etc.).

Input will be two non-negative integers. You should be able to handle either the full range supported by your language's default integer type, or the range `[0,255]`, whichever is greater. You are guaranteed that at least one of the inputs will be non-zero.

You are not allowed to use built-ins that compute either the GCD or the LCM (least common multiple).

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply.

#### Test Cases

```
0 2     => 2
6 0     => 6
30 42   => 6
15 14   => 1
7 7     => 7
69 25   => 1
21 12   => 3
169 123 => 1
20 142  => 2
101 202 => 101
```

Comment: If we're allowing asm to have inputs in whatever registers are convenient, and the result in whatever reg is convenient, we should definitely be allowing functions, or even code fragments (i.e. just a function body).  Making my answer a complete function would add about 4B with a register calling convention like MS's 32bit vectorcall (one xchg eax, one mov, and a ret), or more with a stack calling convention.

Comment: @PeterCordes Sorry, I should have been more specific.  You can totally just write the bear necessary code but if you would be so kind as to include a way to run said code it would be nice.

Comment: So count just the gcd code, but provide the surrounding code so people can verify / experiment / improve?  BTW, your test-cases with zero as one of the two inputs break our x86 machine code answers.  div by zero raises a hardware exception.  On Linux, your process gets a `SIGFPE`.

Comment: @Martin Doesn't your edit make it impossible to implement this in languages where the default integer type is immutable and only limited by the available memory?

Comment: @CodesInChaos Memory and time limitations are usually ignored as long as the algorithm itself can in principle handle all inputs. The rule is just meant to avoid people hardcoding arbitrary limits for loops that artificially limits the algorithm to a smaller range of inputs. I don't quite see how immutability comes into this?

Comment: gcd(0,n) is error not n

Comment: @user58988 Actually, **gcd(0,n) is really n**. **Any number can divide 0 without error**, because 0 divided by any number gives 0. An error can only occur when we try to divide any number **by** zero, which isn't the case in the GCD algorithm

Answer (score 40, accepted):

## [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 16

```
^(.+)\1* \1+$
$1
```

This doesn't use Euclid's algorithm at all - instead it finds the GCD using regex matching groups.

[Try it online.](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=XiguKylcMSogXDErJAokMQ&input=MTExMTExMTEgMTExMTExMTExMTEx) - This example calculates GCD(8,12).

Input as 2 space-separated integers.  Note that the I/O is in unary.  If that is not acceptable, then we can do this:

## Retina, 30

```
\d+
$*
^(.+)\1* \1+$
$1
1+
$.&
```

[Try it online.](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=XGQrCiQqCl4oLispXDEqIFwxKyQKJDEKMSsKJC4m&input=NCA4)

As @MartinBüttner points out, this falls apart for large numbers (as is generally the case for anything unary).  At very a minimum, an input of INT_MAX will require allocation of a 2GB string.

Comment: I would like to vote for this more

Comment: Should be fine with the number range now. I've changed the spec (with the OPs permission) to require only the language's natural number range (or [0,255] if that's more). You'll have to support zeroes though, although I think changing your `+`s to `*`s should do. And you can significantly shorten the last stage of the long code by reducing it to `1`.

Comment: For future reference, I just found an alternative 16-byte solution that works for an arbitrary number of inputs (including one) so it might be more useful in other contexts: http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=XigxKykoID9cMSkqJAokMQ&input=MTExMTExMTEgMTExMTExMTExMTEx

Comment: Just noticed that neither your solutions nor the one in my comment above needs the `^`, because it's impossible for the match to fail from the starting position.

Answer (score 30):

### i386 (x86-32) machine code, 8 bytes  (9B for unsigned)

+1B if we need to handle `b = 0` on input.

### amd64 (x86-64) machine code, 9 bytes (10B for unsigned, or <s>14B</s> 13B for 64b integers signed or unsigned)

### <s>10</s> 9B for unsigned on  amd64 that breaks with either input = 0

---

Inputs are 32bit non-zero *signed* integers in `eax` and `ecx`.  Output in `eax`.

```
## 32bit code, signed integers:  eax, ecx
08048420 <gcd0>:
 8048420:       99                      cdq               ; shorter than xor edx,edx
 8048421:       f7 f9                   idiv   ecx
 8048423:       92                      xchg   edx,eax    ; there's a one-byte encoding for xchg eax,r32.  So this is shorter but slower than a mov
 8048424:       91                      xchg   ecx,eax    ; eax = divisor(from ecx), ecx = remainder(from edx), edx = quotient(from eax) which we discard
    ; loop entry point if we need to handle ecx = 0
 8048425:       41                      inc    ecx        ; saves 1B vs. test/jnz in 32bit mode
 8048426:       e2 f8                   loop   8048420 <gcd0>
08048428 <gcd0_end>:
 ; 8B total
 ; result in eax: gcd(a,0) = a
```

This loop structure fails the test-case where `ecx = 0`.  (`div` causes a `#DE` hardware execption on divide by zero.   (On Linux, the kernel delivers a `SIGFPE` (floating point exception)).  If the loop entry point was right before the `inc`, we'd avoid the problem.  The x86-64 version can handle it for free, see below.

**Mike Shlanta's answer was the starting point for this**.  My loop does the same thing as his, but for signed integers because `cdq` is one byter shorter than `xor edx,edx`.  And yes, it does work correctly with one or both inputs negative.  Mike's version will run faster and take less space in the uop cache (`xchg` is 3 uops on Intel CPUs, and [`loop` is really slow on most CPUs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742570/why-is-the-loop-instruction-slow-couldnt-intel-have-implemented-it-efficiently)), but this version wins at machine-code size.

I didn't notice at first that the question required **unsigned** 32bit.  Going back to `xor edx,edx` instead of `cdq` would cost one byte.  `div` is the same size as `idiv`, and everything else can stay the same (`xchg` for data movement and `inc/loop` still work.)

Interestingly, for 64bit operand-size (`rax` and `rcx`), signed and unsigned versions are the same size.  The signed version needs a REX prefix for `cqo` (2B), but the unsigned version can still use 2B `xor edx,edx`.

In 64bit code, `inc ecx` is 2B: the single-byte `inc r32` and `dec r32` opcodes were repurposed as REX prefixes.  `inc/loop` doesn't save any code-size in 64bit mode, so you might as well `test/jnz`.  Operating on 64bit integers adds another one byte per instruction in REX prefixes, except for `loop` or `jnz`.  It's possible for the remainder to have all zeros in the low 32b (e.g. `gcd((2^32), (2^32 + 1))`), so we need to test the whole rcx and can't save a byte with `test ecx,ecx`.  However, the slower `jrcxz` insn is only 2B, **and we can put it at the top of the loop to handle `ecx=0` on entry**:

```
## 64bit code, unsigned 64 integers:  rax, rcx
0000000000400630 <gcd_u64>:
  400630:       e3 0b                   jrcxz  40063d <gcd_u64_end>   ; handles rcx=0 on input, and smaller than test rcx,rcx/jnz
  400632:       31 d2                   xor    edx,edx                ; same length as cqo
  400634:       48 f7 f1                div    rcx                      ; REX prefixes needed on three insns
  400637:       48 92                   xchg   rdx,rax
  400639:       48 91                   xchg   rcx,rax
  40063b:       eb f3                   jmp    400630 <gcd_u64>
000000000040063d <gcd_u64_end>:
## 0xD = 13 bytes of code
## result in rax: gcd(a,0) = a
```

---

Full runnable test program including a `main` that runs `printf("...", gcd(atoi(argv[1]), atoi(argv[2])) );` **[source and asm output on the Godbolt Compiler Explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g510,options:%27-xc+-Wall+-Wextra+-std%3Dgnu11+-fverbose-asm+-O3+-m32+-masm%3Dintel+-mtune%3Dintel%27,sourcez:PTAEEMBtNBLA7Azk0BXRBTAJhATh0DWAFwAsNdREEBzSDAWgHsAHC8eHJygDwGNSNADRUmoMrEQQ%2BxVFEgBPUAHduAaynKSpUADpwxYgH1EC%2BMXA9Q8VvgBmsHgCgQoAEKpioPkwC2LWHoVbVAGX3BEXwBeBGIMGAAjDD5wdAIyAiYMygA3CmomeFAACgQ%2BSFQsbFA7blB7Cgx4PgwAShUmVEgcBPxwNV0XMDDZeAwY83jQGib2OKlIQppQADkAeQAFKQREOPAuO1Bw%2BCVqeDpGBIU41c3EEVrKDNAEhHBcJU7iFk8nIdAAMJ%2BAL0KQcHCqXAabzcfAyRQ1OphADMACYSmjXl4fFVWiI6gA2AAsWJhVQAXKFfDw0aAkb5iYMnLsDLA%2BHBzNM%2BFhSpzwCJYi92gBvJygcUQSIlVwAIl0sXiJjMFisNhY9kcAB14DKxRLQDKAFb%2BcW6AAyTWIHwApFFtTLQK4AKrNPy%2BS3iMSkcFBLCwHIMK4MABeFCYIiuhEmuFo4nIoEWrA5cYIvlgWCw9F04rcGEMFEpAANDckeMHHaBjSxCwmmEndrhUDJUPgE7A1Ol48SEqA8rgCvA/vr9XKWKioLAaEUifaAJDDhfD1wTqeeo79AjUUMMHyocyxjARWAUPWLmU0bkABkp4u5AEdtZriA7FwvXNRVxgeHFOIRLBziDEbAeHJQ8eGzUA1jGF5rk3UhuDiJ5vSKHg6mAoRgNPBcXwXdN/X1Ut7Sw4ccOHfhBAIywRGA%2B0JVcbIMAAcjBOkxkDWCoxxWNHlAcjljAoRcDRCCAGUxAkbYpEQeDcEQl5PCoRZlAoOMOAgI4mByYiR1fPjKJ4ai%2BB4WjxVcMDQCiUA/RySRuGKUs8UIIyLPqDBwgQKpcHsrAeEc4CXJod4EnAGZVK8ZTgmgbx6HeBMDBPec5QtcwbSickiNfA1XzKYdCJ1V933APIpAARjcXtEGzeZiGAQ14HLBBQExEgNKqEQbGgxru1ajBtIlUj9UTFh9QvLBLwys9RsvIwmiwdKdT68VKWAAAqOlPB%2BYgpBWsADQAanAB1inARyZT2vgZWKBJWkW0BlrWhBNu23bHTAGh/SaSVXP2BhlBjG4vie277uipgEiSftQB2g1gN1V9WgAbiw/BZFwIpwCRgBfP4AGJYDsKpDiMIxwF8LBiWJoY8eaCoqlAAAeXY/XMXRSAAPicYgFDYQm0CQScxhwRZzlrEWukgJHXBpdEAEE3AASRKMJpfaXZAhgb0pGarxhZoQZnTOZZUFiCmvHe4rQBYBDwFeSASCUZR3ngWgpDsXA/EtmNzEOJIUjSOBiGYvmP0F0XlkasJiR6kREDEFqsCYDBkEYrxwmIAQU1Aa1xeTdVYkOR406oK0Xb%2BFliDZNAotG1BiWKHP%2BSrxIRSwiJfGlMA5QVSAlXMf81Q1YyFsy0dxzt1cZ2H19z25Ixa6Jea4en19DVwIzy3FUa54p2aTMKi2yoqqqk68NeDLPis6uDERwVAZDMyT%2BojKiS9WI5TbEUoN2MF6kfdLqAiPkMI%2BUfM%2BfUrhQzu0IN%2BWa9R/yxDELgHy5JcBUSoKTTcsBQxfT4HeMQxQABKABRAAGt4LAd4bp/0XNZYcZ8Jpnl0gIZYEpUEGXqCA/K4CwAMSDuAVilwOJNC4iLHiekBJCVRKJcSpBJBwCkjJOSCQFKICUipMgal%2BG%2BE0rdAaEo9KsLQfQrhdEwBsJctZWyXkz6OQvpZfA7lOAUGKEg3yIhXEBSCiFTsBgVAEC0FFcoh5KCQHirgXRK8TQjVnvPBhJEt7zxmpwRewNHRrUBp4Z64ozqHRKCdEQZ0LpXSoa%2BEGj1MlQxeq4c2n0IjfSwL9f6mQNqZNSatUG4N8iVJhj5JeC5EbIzzC2dGWMnA41mvjP4zILAV3ZHuEO1Qt7SVCX3eu/MpzVEbvMgW1RrqgFFPqNuHcDTykmD3UwfdVS2AwA4IeL5XA%2BH8IEfxIQwhtwmHESAi1R4rmnHEkcU0jCbBScvfRACJToRolPbC%2BpaEEQSHc75%2BptE5FylRDACL/n9WRZpXKCLgGItBeKaq8KDIYsJYwiUV9hyAs2ERWcM8xpAo2Ekua9K7r7VycdU6e0EiXWuk4ec5JBUcplLDQVAz9Qo2GRAUZThtkbJwEs1ACQ1kLJwFs9Zoc9kHNMX4qyeZkjhXIEUHsK1fZ%2BCTmtSB4ZrBZDgIcEgfDIB9CwEoG1WEHnkD4GoT%2BAd1pbXTJ2AgRyWDvC8LHfVKQihqyiiS54WRyBfz3DIWAhRNAhFfuUraWF8YlAAIQnVcqjU1SN9R5uKPmvZ0q0ays9WAL8Vp%2BH4DvMbBxlpECUnAPml%2BEYe2XlblKYospTmfN7iqO16oblamhSRXQY5fmgEnnozKerF2AXXB2KgWDGC7n3CLQ81ATzT1GogFVtp5pPj6SRW8USs4AG0EgAF1qKWFAaRd8Kq76NA5LsQ8BxvAmhbW2x%2BmiMxrnwH2TA/rGrPEQI7YavQOACCRZWcABBzQ2Hg%2BAFgtp32oYMQJB9z733cO8BwFONRJwtmaV4fhjslAbuw8NLQZBAO4sanYDAylKBXHmN8zDTBmMXvw6Cs9PZxTWkfS%2Bv8Q8r2obqgQTe3JxN4dnQClTKrWUifUxKEGGStrdM5UdfJoBpP7VwPy9or0XhWUTsnLw3o8hriSMmUsMcxD0DNnwOZ0HlDejiH2f1jtzCIEWmU%2BAT0jM2ZqejKQrrGkkFo0DUpaSOkQ2eotSVrChm1oxk4bGuMyi0wIIzYgfomCsw5tTcolRStMztgkKrYzit1YZhETAslmuCkcbyOjuALwiAEO8Fa7waA5HvU%2Bm6urxQdYoMQY6A2%2BBs1RNl8Ugp%2BGWQMEwWAi3xv3pKlNiMLltu7bGxN1EU2y0Sjzt7YojLijWiwCIJ77RLJPbpJQbOn2s6oHtDfCMIhRrHSENdIHs9lkcAsCDsHXIsAmBVTD9oAy8YExuaAYmpNyZEkpvqHOoSXINkAuLPbE3DsiBWE6M0ZoRCXkcpAHslkiedGgKT%2B9l2KdU5p6AOn13xS3eIHYe7wPrTQFQC9sXb2s5i9AFz/7cURAM/B1geexRQlCAZ8jpG4zOCTKlblool5RlAAAA%3D)),filterAsm:(binary:!t,commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3)**, for the 32 and 64b versions.  Tested and working for 32bit (`-m32`), 64bit (`-m64`), and the [x32 ABI (`-mx32`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI).

Also included: a version using [repeated subtraction only](http://www.naturalnumbers.org/EuclidSubtract.html), which is 9B for unsigned, even for x86-64 mode, and can take one of its inputs in an arbitrary register.  However, it can't handle either input being 0 on entry (it detect when `sub` produces a zero, which x - 0 never does).

GNU C inline asm source for the 32bit version (compile with `gcc -m32 -masm=intel`)

```
int gcd(int a, int b) {
    asm (// ".intel_syntax noprefix\n"
        // "jmp  .Lentry%=\n" // Uncomment to handle div-by-zero, by entering the loop in the middle.  Better: `jecxz / jmp` loop structure like the 64b version
        ".p2align 4\n"                  // align to make size-counting easier
         "gcd0:   cdq\n\t"              // sign extend eax into edx:eax.  One byte shorter than xor edx,edx
         "        idiv    ecx\n"
         "        xchg    eax, edx\n"   // there's a one-byte encoding for xchg eax,r32.  So this is shorter but slower than a mov
         "        xchg    eax, ecx\n"   // eax = divisor(ecx), ecx = remainder(edx), edx = garbage that we will clear later
         ".Lentry%=:\n"
         "        inc     ecx\n"        // saves 1B vs. test/jnz in 32bit mode, none in 64b mode
         "        loop    gcd0\n"
        "gcd0_end:\n"
         : /* outputs */  "+a" (a), "+c"(b)
         : /* inputs */   // given as read-write outputs
         : /* clobbers */ "edx"
        );
    return a;
}
```

Normally I'd write a whole function in asm, but GNU C inline asm seems to be the best way to include a snippet which can have in/outputs in whatever regs we choose.  As you can see, GNU C inline asm syntax makes asm ugly and noisy.  It's also a [really difficult way to *learn* asm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34520013/using-base-pointer-register-in-c-inline-asm/34522750#34522750).

It would actually compile and work in `.att_syntax noprefix` mode, because all the insns used are either single/no operand or `xchg`.  Not really a useful observation.

Comment: @MikeShlanta: Thanks.  If you like optimizing asm, have a look at some of my answers over on stackoverflow. :)

Comment: @MikeShlanta: I found a use for `jrcxz` after all in the uint64_t version :).  Also, didn't notice that you'd specified unsigned, so I included byte counts for that, too.

Comment: Why couldn't you use `jecxz` in the 32-bit version to the same effect?

Comment: @CodyGray: `inc/loop` is 3 bytes in the 32-bit version, but 4B in the 64-bit version.  That means that in the 64-bit version only, it doesn't cost extra bytes to use `jrcxz` and `jmp` instead of `inc / loop`.

Comment: Can't you point to the middle as entry?

Comment: @l4m2: [Yes, you can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35468465/does-a-function-with-instructions-before-the-entry-point-label-cause-problems-fo).  But not with inline asm.  Good point, I should update this answer to leave out the +1B for handling 0 on entry.  Oh, but this is only a snippet, not a function, and in asm it's not free if the surrounding code can't just fall into / out of it.  If I want it to be a function, I need to include a `ret`.  (This was one of my first answers.  I normally post functions now, but this question was originally written to allow a snippet, not a function.)

Comment: The current question seem doesn't say to allow snippet

Comment: @l4m2: yeah, I know, but I'm just going to leave it alone.  I'm going to let myself get away with it on a technicality, because it's just one byte either way, and I don't want to take the time to re-edit the answer.  It wasn't the OP's edit that changed it; it was originally written as an ASM-encouraging question, but a mod changed it to be a normal code-golf question.  I answered the original question, so I think it's fine to leave it.

Answer (score 15):

### [Hexagony](https://github.com/mbuettner/hexagony), 17 bytes

```
?'?>}!@<\=%)>{\.(
```

Unfolded:

```
  ? ' ?
 > } ! @
< \ = % )
 > { \ .
  ( . .
```

[Try it online!](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=Pyc_Pn0hQDxcPSUpPntcLig&input=MzAgNDI)

Fitting it into side-length 3 was a breeze. Shaving off those two bytes at the end wasn't... I'm also not convinced it's optimal, but I'm sure I think it's close.

#### Explanation

Another Euclidean algorithm implementation.

The program uses three memory edges, which I'll call **A**, **B** and **C**, with the memory pointer (MP) starting out as shown:

[image]

Here is the control flow diagram:

[image]

Control flow starts on the grey path with a short linear bit for input:

```
?    Read first integer into memory edge A.
'    Move MP backwards onto edge B.
?    Read second integer into B.
```

Note that the code now wraps around the edges to the `<` in the left corner. This `<` acts as a branch. If the current edge is zero (i.e. the Euclidean algorithm terminates), the IP is deflected to the left and takes the red path. Otherwise, an iteration of the Euclidean algorithm is computed on the green path.

We'll first consider the green path. Note that `>` and `\` all acts as mirrors which simply deflect the instruction pointer. Also note that control flow wraps around the edges three times, once from the bottom to the top, once from the right corner to the bottom row and finally from the bottom right corner to the left corner to re-check the condition. Also note that `.` are no-ops.

That leaves the following linear code for a single iteration:

```
{    Move MP forward onto edge C.
'}   Move to A and back to C. Taken together this is a no-op.
=    Reverse the direction of the MP so that it now points at A and B. 
%    Compute A % B and store it in C.
)(   Increment, decrement. Taken together this is a no-op, but it's
     necessary to ensure that IP wraps to the bottom row instead of
     the top row.
```

Now we're back where we started, except that the three edges have changed their roles cyclically (the original **C** now takes the role of **B** and the original **B** the role of **A**...). In effect, we've relpaced inputs `A` and `B` with `B` and `A % B`, respectively.

Once `A % B` (on edge **C**) is zero, the GCD can be found on edge **B**. Again the `>` just deflects the IP, so on the red path we execute:

```
}    Move MP to edge B.
!    Print its value as an integer.
@    Terminate the program.
```

Answer (score 11):

## T-SQL, 153 <s>169</s> bytes

Someone mentioned worst language for golfing?

```
CREATE FUNCTION G(@ INT,@B INT)RETURNS TABLE RETURN WITH R AS(SELECT 1D,0R UNION ALL SELECT D+1,@%(D+1)+@B%(D+1)FROM R WHERE D<@ and D<@b)SELECT MAX(D)D FROM R WHERE 0=R
```

Creates a table valued function <s>that uses a recursive query to work out the common divisors.  Then it returns the maximum</s>.
Now uses the euclidean algorithm to determine the GCD derived from my answer [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/58831/31347).

Example usage

```
SELECT * 
FROM (VALUES
        (15,45),
        (45,15),
        (99,7),
        (4,38)
    ) TestSet(A, B)
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM G(A,B))GCD

A           B           D
----------- ----------- -----------
15          45          15
45          15          15
99          7           1
4           38          2

(4 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Jesus that is verbose.

Answer (score 10):

## Jelly, 7 bytes

```
ṛß%ðḷṛ?
```

Recursive implementation of the Euclidean algorithm. [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bmbw58lw7DhuLfhuZs_&input=&args=MTI+MTU)

If built-ins weren't forbidden, `g` (1 byte, built-in GCD) would achieve a better score.

#### How it works

```
ṛß%ðḷṛ?  Main link. Arguments: a, b

   ð     Convert the chain to the left into a link; start a new, dyadic chain.
 ß       Recursively call the main link...
ṛ %        with b and a % b as arguments.
     ṛ?  If the right argument (b) is non-zero, execute the link.
    ḷ    Else, yield the left argument (a).
```

Comment: That almost feels like cheating haha, I may have to specify that answers can't use butlins...

Comment: If you decide to do so, you should do it quickly. It would currently invalidate three of the answers.

Comment: Notice he specified length is in bytes -- those characters are mostly > 1 byte in UTF8.

Comment: @cortices Yes, all code golf contests are scored in bytes by default. However, Jelly doesn't use UTF-8, but a [custom code page](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page) that encodes each of the 256 characters it understands as a single byte.

Answer (score 10):

### 32-bit little-endian x86 machine code, 14 bytes

Generated using `nasm -f bin`

`d231 f3f7 d889 d389 db85 f475`

```
    gcd0:   xor     edx,edx
            div     ebx
            mov     eax,ebx
            mov     ebx,edx
            test    ebx,ebx
            jnz     gcd0
```

Comment: I got this down to 8 bytes by using `cdq` and signed `idiv`, and one-byte `xchg eax, r32` instead of `mov`.  For 32bit code: `inc/loop` instead of `test/jnz` (I couldn't see a way to use `jecxz`, and there's no `jecxnz`).  I posted my final version as a new answer since I think the changes are big enough to justify it.

Answer (score 8):

## Python 3, 31

Saved 3 bytes thanks to Sp3000.

```
g=lambda a,b:b and g(b,a%b)or a
```

Comment: In Python 3.5+: `from math import*;gcd`

Comment: @Sp3000 Nice, I didn't know they had moved it to math.

Comment: While you're at it: `g=lambda a,b:b and g(b,a%b)or a`

Comment: @Sp3000 Thanks! I just finished a recursive solution, but that's even better than what I had.

Comment: Built-ins for GCD and LCM are disallowed, so the 2nd solution wouldn't be valid.

Comment: @mbomb007 I'll remove it. That rule didn't exist when I added that one.

Answer (score 7):

### Haskell, 19 bytes

```
a#0=a
a#b=b#rem a b
```

Usage example: `45 # 35`-> `5`.

Euclid, again.

PS: of course there's a built-in `gcd`, too.

Comment: you should explain the trick that reverses the input order to avoid the conditional check

Comment: @proudhaskeller: what trick? Everybody uses this algorithm, i.e. stopping on `0` or going on with the modulus.

Comment: Nevrmind, everybody is using the trick

Comment: This, less golfed, is almost exactly what's in `Prelude`

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), <s>11</s> 9 bytes

No one seems to have used brute force up to now, so here it is.

```
ts:\a~f0)
```

Input is a column array with the two numbers (using `;` as separator).

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v6TYKiaxLs1A8///aGMDaxOjWAA) or [**verify all test cases**](https://tio.run/##HYoxEoAgDAR7f2KXBJDRa32CHTAjjZVWUvv1GGhu5/buqe3WU9u75fpdNOt@aCJImdICsnQE3xsHsDdGxL6tkGAUBo/VBIvrhuw3FDGEpPw).

#### Explanation

```
t     % Take input [a;b] implicitly. Duplicate
s     % Sum. Gives a+b
:     % Array [1,2,...,a+b]
\     % Modulo operation with broadcast. Gives a 2×(a+b) array
a~    % 1×(a+b) array that contains true if the two modulo operations gave 0
f0)   % Index of last true value. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 5):

## Julia, <s>21</s> 15 bytes

```julia
a\b=a>0?b%a\a:b
```

Recursive implementation of the Euclidean algorithm. [Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=YVxiPWE-MD9iJWFcYTpiCgpmb3IgKGEsYikgaW4gKCgwLDIpLCAoNiwwKSwgKDMwLDQyKSwgKDE1LDE0KSwgKDcsNyksICg2OSwyNSksICgyMSwxMiksICgxNjksMTIzKSwgKDIwLDE0MiksICgxMDEsIDIwMikpCiAgICBAcHJpbnRmKCIlM2QgJTNkID0-ICUzZFxuIixhLGIsYVxiKQplbmQ&input=)

If built-ins weren't forbidden, `gcd` (3 bytes, built-in GCD) would achieve a better score.

#### How it works

```
a\b=             Redefine the binary operator \ as follows:
    a>0?     :       If a > 0:
        b%a\a        Resursively apply \ to b%a and a. Return the result.
              b      Else, return b.
```

Answer (score 5):

### TI-Basic, 27 bytes

```
Prompt A,B:While B:B→T:BfPart(A/B→B:T→A:End:A
```

---

**35 byte** recursive solution without `gcd(` or `lcm(` built-ins (requires 2.53 MP operating system or higher, *must be named* `prgmG`):

```
If Ans(2:Then:{Ans(2),remainder(Ans(1),Ans(2:prgmG:Else:Disp Ans(1:End
```

You would pass arguments to the recursive variant as `{A,B}` so for example `{1071, 462}:prgmG` would yield `21`.

## TI-Basic, 10 bytes

```
Prompt A,B:gcd(A,B
```

*Not allowed due to new rule forbidding gcd built-ins*

---

**17 byte** solution without `gcd(` built-in

```
Prompt A,B:abs(AB)/lcm(A,B
```

*Not allowed due to new rule forbidding lcm built-ins*

---

Comment: Color me impressed.

Comment: You should probably mention that the last one needs to be saved as `prgmG`.

Answer (score 5):

## C, 38 bytes

```
g(x,y){while(x^=y^=x^=y%=x);return y;}
```

Comment: You need to include the definition of the function in your bytecount.

Comment: @Riker sorry for that, I add the definition and update the count

Comment: You can save two bytes by naming the function just `g` instead of `gcd`.

Comment: @Steadybox ok, yes, first time join this community:)

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 4):

### C#, 24 bytes

```
x=(a,b)=>b<1?a:x(b,a%b);
```

Answer (score 4):

## C, 28 bytes

A rather straightforward function implementing Euclid's algorithm. Perhaps one can get shorter using an alternate algorithm.

```
g(a,b){return b?g(b,a%b):a;}
```

If one writes a little main wrapper

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("gcd(%d, %d) = %d\n", atoi(argv[1]), atoi(argv[2]), g(atoi(argv[1]), atoi(argv[2])));
}
```

then one can test a few values:

```
$ ./gcd 6 21
gcd(6, 21) = 3
$ ./gcd 21 6
gcd(21, 6) = 3
$ ./gcd 6 8
gcd(6, 8) = 2
$ ./gcd 1 1
gcd(1, 1) = 1
$ ./gcd 6 16
gcd(6, 16) = 2
$ ./gcd 27 244
gcd(27, 244) = 1
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 10 <s>12</s> bytes

```
?v%uII/;O@
```

[Try it here](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix)

This wraps onto the cube as follows:

```
    ? v
    % u
I I / ; O @ . .
. . . . . . . .
    . .
    . .
```

Uses the Euclidean Method.

`II` Two numbers are grabbed from STDIN and put on the stack
`/` Flow reflected up
`%` Mod the Top of Stack.  Remainder left on top of stack
`?` If TOS 0 then carry on, otherwise turn right
`v` If not 0 then redirect down and `u` turn right twice back onto the mod
`/` If 0 go around the cube to the reflector
`;` drop TOS, `O` output TOS and `@` end

Comment: I just wrote up a 12-byte Cubix answer, then started scrolling through the answers to see if I needed to handle both `0,x` and `x,0`... then I came across this. Nice one!

Answer (score 4):

### [Labyrinth](https://github.com/mbuettner/labyrinth/), 18 bytes

```
?}
:
)"%{!
( =
}:{
```

Terminates with an error, but the error message goes to STDERR.

[Try it online!](http://labyrinth.tryitonline.net/#code=P30KOgopIiV7IQooID0KfTp7&input=MzAgNDI)

This doesn't feel quite optimal yet, but I'm not seeing a way to compress the loop below 3x3 at this point.

#### Explanation

This uses the Euclidean algorithm.

First, there's a linear bit to read input and get into the main loop. The instruction pointer (IP) starts in the top left corner, going east.

```
?    Read first integer from STDIN and push onto main stack.
}    Move the integer over to the auxiliary stack.
     The IP now hits a dead end so it turns around.
?    Read the second integer.
     The IP hits a corner and follows the bend, so it goes south.
:    Duplicate the second integer.
)    Increment.
     The IP is now at a junction. The top of the stack is guaranteed to be
     positive, so the IP turns left, to go east.
"    No-op.
%    Modulo. Since `n % (n+1) == n`, we end up with the second input on the stack.
```

We now enter a sort of while-do loop which computes the Euclidean algorithm. The tops of the stacks contain `a` and `b` (on top of an implicit infinite amount of zeros, but we won't need those). We'll represent the stacks side to side, growing towards each other:

```
    Main     Auxiliary
[ ... 0 a  |  b 0 ... ]
```

The loop terminates once `a` is zero. A loop iteration works as follows:

```
=    Swap a and b.           [ ... 0 b  |  a 0 ... ]
{    Pull a from aux.        [ ... 0 b a  |  0 ... ]
:    Duplicate.              [ ... 0 b a a  |  0 ... ]
}    Move a to aux.          [ ... 0 b a  |  a 0 ... ]
()   Increment, decrement, together a no-op.
%    Modulo.                 [ ... 0 (b%a)  |  a 0 ... ]
```

You can see, we've replaced `a` and `b` with `b%a` and `a` respectively.

Finally, once `b%a` is zero, the IP keeps moving east and executes:

```
{    Pull the non-zero value, i.e. the GCD, over from aux.
!    Print it.
     The IP hits a dead end and turns around.
{    Pull a zero from aux.
%    Attempt modulo. This fails due to division by 0 and the program terminates.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 5 bytes

```
ḋˢ⊇ᵛ×
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3w/@GO7tOLHnW1P9w6@/D0//@jFaINdIxidaLNdAyApLGBjgmIZ2iqY2gCpM11zEFyljpGpkDayFDHECwLFDA0MgaJGADVgYUMDHWMDIxiFWIB)

Takes input as a list through the input variable and outputs an integer through the output variable. If you use it as a generator, it actually generates all common divisors, it just does so largest first.

```
         The output is
    ×    the product of the elements of
  ⊇      the maximal sublist
   ᵛ     which is shared by
ḋ        the prime factorization
 ˢ       s of the elements of the input which have them.
```

Answer (score 3):

## Windows Batch, 76 bytes

Recursive function. Call it like `GCD a b` with file name `gcd`.

```
:g
if %2 equ 0 (set f=%1
goto d)
set/a r=%1 %% %2
call :g %2 %r%
:d
echo %f%
```

Answer (score 3):

## MATL, 7 bytes

```
pG1$Zm/
```

[**Try it Online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=cEcxJFptLw&input=WzE1LDNd)

**Explanation**

Since we can't explicitly use the builtin GCD function (`Zd` in MATL), I have exploited the fact that the least common multiple of `a` and `b` times the greatest common denominator of `a` and `b` is equal to the product of `a` and `b`.

```
p       % Grab the input implicitly and multiply the two elements
G       % Grab the input again, explicitly this time
1$Zm    % Compute the least-common multiple
/       % Divide the two to get the greatest common denominator
```

Comment: You can save one byte with two separate inputs: `*1MZm/`

Answer (score 3):

### ARM machine code, 12 bytes:

assembly:

```
gcd: cmp r0, r1
     sublt r0, r0, r1
     bne gcd
```

Currently can't compile this, but each instruction in ARM takes 4 bytes. Probably it could be golfed down using THUMB-2 mode.

Comment: Nice job man anyone who does this in machine code gets serious props from me.

Comment: This appears to be an attempt at [Euclid's algo using only subtraction](http://www.naturalnumbers.org/EuclidSubtract.html), but I don't think it works.  If `r0 > r1` then `sublt` will do nothing (`lt` predicate is false) and `bne` will be an infinite loop.  I think you need a swap if not `lt`, so the same loop can do `b-=a` or `a-=b` as needed.  Or a negate if the sub produced carry (aka borrow).

Comment: This [ARM instruction set guide](http://simplemachines.it/doc/arm_inst.pdf) actually uses a subtraction GCD algorithm as an example for predication.  (pg 25).  They use `cmp r0, r1` / `subgt r0, r0, r1` / `sublt r1, r1, r0` / `bne gcd`.  That's 16B in ARM instructions, maybe 12 in thumb2 instructions?

Comment: On x86, I managed 9 bytes with: `sub ecx, eax` / `jae .no_swap` / `add ecx,eax` / `xchg ecx,eax` / `jne`.  So instead of a cmp, I just sub, then undo and swap if the sub should have gone the other way.  I tested this, and it works.  (`add` won't make `jne` exit at the wrong time, because it can't produce a zero unless one of the inputs was zero to start with, and we don't support that.  Update: we do need to support either input being zero :/)

Comment: For Thumb2, there's an `ite` instruction: if-then-else.  Should be perfect for cmp / sub one way / sub the other way.

Answer (score 3):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 32 bytes

```
::{::}@(?\=?v{:}-
.!09}}${{/;n/>
```

Accepts two values from the stack and apply the euclidian algorithm to produce their GCD.

You can try it [here](https://fishlanguage.com/playground)!

For a much better answer in ><>, check out [Sok's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/81126/41881) !

Comment: I found a new language today :)

Answer (score 3):

## Racket (Scheme), 44 bytes

Euclid implementation in Racket (Scheme)

```
(define(g a b)(if(= 0 b)a(g b(modulo a b))))
```

Edit: Didn't see @Numeri 's solution lol. Somehow we got the exact same code independently

Comment: Does this work in both?

Comment: @NoOneIsHere yeah it works in both

Answer (score 3):

## R, <s>39</s> 33 bytes

Surprised not to see an R answer on here yet. A recursive implementation of the Euclidean algorithm. Saved 2 bytes due to Giuseppe.

```
g=pryr::f(`if`(o<-x%%y,g(y,o),y))
```

And here is a vectorized version (**35 bytes**) which works well for problems like [Natural pi calculation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/95256/59052).

```
g=pryr::f(ifelse(o<-x%%y,g(y,o),y))
```

Comment: `"if"` rather than `ifelse` for -2 bytes, but you lose the vectorization...

Comment: @Giuseppe Thanks, good catch!

Answer (score 3):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 21 bytes

```
f=(a,b)=>b?f(b,a%b):a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BCsMgEETvfsVeCm7Zg5qkIQHbDyk9KFTwEoPxVvrt1jRo9jTDmxl2jSGFJWenuSGL@m4fjlsyF4uzyem9pQ00PBmU44JAIR36RiCq7groG5EDgeyrGwnG1pnKwFCdkiV3tnYoVdeo2FdOLEpaCYXsxZgLETzMcLz3@SfW6JfEHb96RPbNPw)

Shush you, this is totally not a port of the Python answer.

Comment: Conditional operator is shorter: `f=(x,y)=>y? f(y,x%y):x` (yes the space is necessary due to an interpreter bug)

Comment: ...Right, I need to start thinking Proton, not Python. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [ReRegex](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ReRegex), 23 bytes

Works identically to the Retina answer.

```
^(_*)\1* \1*$/$1/#input
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otSk1Prfj/P04jXkszxlBLAYhV9FUM9ZUz8wpKS/7/j4cChXgkAAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 26 bytes

```
D,g,@@#~,%A$p%+
L,MRBCþgbM
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99FJ13HwUG5TkfVUaVAVZvLR8c3yMn58L70JN//KjmJuUkpiQqGdvZ29lz@//8bG/w3MQIA)

Generates the range \$1, 2, 3, ..., \max(a, b)\$, then filters out elements that don't divide either \$a\$ or \$b\$, Finally, we return the maximum value of the filtered elements.

Answer (score 3):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), <sup><s>37</s></sup> 34 bytes

```forth
: f dup if tuck mod recurse then ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5BDoIwEEX3c4of95JOQYgaPYkbAkWISMlQ9Pg4khTtpnnzX@e38RLa/b35XstyQoN6HtE1CHP1wNPXEFfNMjmE1g04qxLcFAjwLydIVj3BDaN0Q0B4e5Ryn9AN8FI7UTHZ4XLFDuuJYini3xpqX4JKYliVfa@zcqjjwtbpD6a5D3QmMrBrvZqWcpgIOaUGmf0hH8BZRKYCRYSC8iPs4ZdZBm8vU2KN2aZ/udFVf7VsGNZsA8XlAw)

Same as the code below, but using recursion instead. Turns out that the combination `if then recurse` is shorter than `begin while repeat` by 3 chars, even though the word `recurse` looks quite bulky.

---

#### Previous solution, 37 bytes

```forth
: f begin dup while tuck mod repeat ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3NboNADITvfopR7kXrJQG1UfskuWzZ5UelLDJLeHzqIm0SX6zxfJ5po6T@rWv/175/oMV36IYJfp2x9cMYkNbmB7/RQ8IcXMJVqRSWREC8B0FxsAVumGWYEtIW4aRboClRfBAFixM@v3DCMRl0InFTs4Uv0Eg2GzeOenOTz4F90O5lHRNdiQzsUa@kpQomi4pKg7N9Sr6Az1ky1aizqKl6h708Pcvgx2dJrDbb8sU3GvVSy4ZhzeOgcv8D)

Input is two single-cell integers, output is one double-cell integer.

#### How it works

A "cell" means a space for one item on the stack. A double-cell integer in Forth takes two cells, where the most significant cell is on the top. For this challenge, the GCD of two single-cell integers always fits in a cell, so the upper cell is always 0.

```forth
: f ( a b -- d ) \ Define a function f which takes two singles and gives a double
  begin          \ Start a loop
    dup while    \   While b is not zero...
    tuck         \   Copy b under a ( stack: b a b ) and
    mod          \   Calculate a%b  ( stack: b a%b )
                 \   That is, change ( a b ) to ( b a%b )
  repeat ;       \ End loop
                 \ The result is ( gcd 0 ) which is gcd in double-cell
```

Answer (score 3):

### [ARMv7](https://www.arm.com/) ([OakSim](https://github.com/Wunkolo/OakSim)), 28 bytes

Hexdump:

```
0x00010000: 01 00 80 E0 00 10 81 E0 01 00 50 E1 01 00 40 C0 ..........P...@.
0x00010010: 00 10 41 B0 FB FF FF 1A 1E FF 2F E1 00 00 00 00 ..A......./.....
```

### Explanation

Callable function, expects the arguments in `r0` and `r1`, output is in `r0`.

Expects address of caller stored in `lr`. This is the standard method of procedure calling as per the ATPCS (ARM Thumb Procedure Call Standard).

```
gcd:
    add r0, r0, r1        /* Make sure r0 is nonzero */
    add r1, r1, r0        /* Make sure r1 is nonzero */
                          /* We're basically doing the inverse afterwards */

    loop:                 /* main loop: */
        cmp r0, r1        /*     Compare r0 and r1 */
        subgt r0, r0, r1  /*     If r0 >  r1: r0 = r0 - r1 */
        sublt r1, r1, r0  /*     If r0 <  r1: r1 = r1 - r0 */
        bne loop          /*     If r0 != r1: jump back to main loop */

    bx lr                 /* return to caller */
```

#### Example call

```
b caller       /* jump to the caller */
gcd:
               /* omitted to save space */
caller:
    mov r0, 30 /* first operand  = 30 */
    mov r1, 42 /* second operand = 42 */
    mov lr, pc /* link register  = program counter */

    b gcd      /* branch to function */
```

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, 21 bytes.

I think I'm doing this right, I'm still super new to Javascript.

```
g=a=>b=>b?g(b)(a%b):a
```

Comment: That won't work. You define `g` as curried monads, yet use is as a dyadic function.

Comment: @Dennis I think I just fixed it? Like I said, super new to JS.

Comment: Yes, that works. For the record, `g=(a,b)=>b?a:g(b,a%b)` is equally short.

Comment: @Dennis Ahhhh, that's what I was missing. I forgot the parens around the arguments and it was throwing syntax errors.

Comment: Did you intend to put the ternary values the other way around? `g=a=>b=>b?g(b)(a%b):a`

Comment: Doesn't work when `a` is less than `b`

Comment: @ericw31415 Yes it does: if `a<b`, then `a%b == a`, and so the recursive case essentially does `g(b)(a)`, swapping the arguments so that `a` is now larger. A particularly elegant feature of this algorithm!

Comment: @DLosc Wait, this solution doesn't even work for all of the test cases...

Comment: @ericw31415 See user81655's comment. When the ternary is switched around, it should work.

Comment: @DLosc True. I was originally looking for a GCD function to save work in [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/147887/codeium-golfide/148950#148950) but this wouldn't work so I came up with my own solution. Seems like I ended up with the same thing as user81665.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

Code:

```
EàF¹N%O>iN
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=RcOgRsK5TiVPPmlO&input=WzQsIDhd)

---

With built-ins:

```
¿
```

Explanation:

```
¿   # Implicit input, computes the greatest common divisor.
    # Input can be in the form a \n b, which computes gcd(a, b)
    # Input can also be a list in the form [a, b, c, ...], which computes the gcd of
      multiple numbers.
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=wr8&input=NAo4) or [Try with multiple numbers](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=wr8&input=WzQsIDgsIDEwLCAxMl0).

Answer (score 2):

### Hoon, 20 bytes

```
|=
{@ @}
d:(egcd +<)
```

--

### Hoon #2, 39 bytes

```
|=
{a/@ b/@}
?~
b
a
$(a b, b (mod a b))
```

Oddly, the only implementation in Hoon's stdlib for GCD is the one in use for its RSA crypto, which also returns some other values. I have to wrap it in a function that takes only `d` from the output.

The other implementation is just the default recursive GCD definition.

Answer (score 2):

## GML, 57 bytes

```
a=argument0
b=argument1
while b{t=b;b=a mod b;a=t}return a
```

Answer (score 2):

## Delphi 7, 148

Well, I think I've found the new worst language for golfing.

```
unit a;interface function g(a,b:integer):integer;implementation function g(a,b:integer):integer;begin if b=0then g:=a else g:=g(b,a mod b);end;end.
```

Comment: Oh I don't know, [parenthetic](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Parenthetic) is pretty poor for golfing

Comment: Morgan, you may strip the overhead of a UCSD Pascal `unit`. The task just asks for a `program` or `function`.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3.5, <strike>70</strike> <strike>82</strike> 73 bytes:

```
lambda*a:max([i for i in range(1,max(*a)+1)if not sum(g%i for g in[*a])])
```

The `not` in this case will make sure the sum all the numbers in `*args` modulo `i` are zero.

Also, now this lambda function can take in as many values as you want it to, as long as the amount of values is `>=2`, unlike the `gcd` function of the math module. For instance, it can take in the values `2,4,6,8,10` and return the correct GCD of 2.

Comment: You're under arrest for multichar variable names. (Or function arguments, but whatever)

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 23 bytes

```
g=->a,b{b>0?a:g[b,a%b]}
```

*remember that ruby blocks are called with g[...] or g.call(...), instead of g(...)*

*partial credits to voidpigeon*

Comment: Instead of `g.call(a,b)` you can use `g[a,b]`. Instead of `proc{|a,b|`, you can use `->a,b{`.

Comment: You can also save one byte by using `b>0` instead of `b<=0` and switching the order of the other operands.

Answer (score 2):

## Oracle SQL 11.2, <s>104</s> 118 bytes

```
SELECT MAX(:1+:2-LEVEL+1)FROM DUAL WHERE(MOD(:1,:1+:2-LEVEL+1)+MOD(:2,:1+:2-LEVEL+1))*:1*:2=0 CONNECT BY LEVEL<=:1+:2;
```

Fixed for input of 0

Comment: Does not work correctly if one of inputs is zero.

Comment: This should save you a few `SELECT MAX(LEVEL)FROM DUAL WHERE MOD(:1,LEVEL)+MOD(:2,LEVEL)=0 CONNECT BY LEVEL<=:1+:2;`

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, 42 bytes

```
n=(x,y)=>{for(k=x;x%k+y%k>0;k--);alert(k)}
```

I could get it down to ~32 with [Grond](https://github.com/epicTCK/Grond/blob/master/Grond.js), but whatever

Comment: You can save a byte with currying.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work with the new test cases (in particular, **0, 2**).

Comment: What is currying?

Comment: Dennis, `0 / 2 != 2`. I say the test cases are wrong... *sneaky face*

Answer (score 2):

## Scheme, 44 bytes

```
(define(f a b)(if(= b 0)a(f b(modulo a b))))
```

Scheme is the future of code-golf. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 12+3 = 15 bytes

```
:?!\:}%
;n~/
```

Expects the input numbers to be present on the stack, so +3 bytes for the `-v` flag. [Try it online!](http://fish.tryitonline.net/#code=Oj8hXDp9JQo7bn4v&input=&args=LXYgMjA+LXYgMTQy)

Another implementation of the Euclidean algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

## Maple, <s>77</s> 75 bytes

```
`if`(min(a,b)=0,max(a,b),max(`intersect`(op(numtheory:-divisors~({a,b})))))
```

Usage:

```
> f:=(a,b)->ifelse(min(a,b)=0,max(a,b),max(`intersect`(op(numtheory:-divisors~({a,b})))));
> f(0,6);
  6
> f(21,12);
  3
```

This uses a Maple deprecated built-in for computing all of the factors for `a` and `b`. The updated [built-in](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=NumberTheory/Divisors) is `NumberTheory:-Divisors`.

Answer (score 2):

### Racket 38 bytes

```
  (λ(a b)(if(> b 0)(f b(modulo a b))a))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define f
  (λ (a b)
    (if (<= b 0)
        a
        (f b (modulo a b))
        )))
```

Testing:

```
(f 0 2)
(f 6 0)
(f 30 42)
(f 15 14)
(f 7 7)
(f 69 25)
(f 21 12)
(f 169 123)
(f 20 142)
(f 101 202)
```

Output:

```
2
6
6
1
7
1
3
1
2
101
```

Comment: Built-ins are disallowed in the challenge specification.

Comment: I have corrected the answer.

Answer (score 2):

### [Logy](https://github.com/logy-lang/logy), <s>64</s> 23 bytes

```
f[X,Y]->Y<1&X|f[Y,X%Y];
```

Ungolfed:

```
gcd[X, Y] -> Y < 1 & X | gcd[Y, X%Y];
```

EDIT: Removed way too many bytes because there is no need for a full program

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>44</s> 37 bytes

Here is a straight up, non-recursive (because of the lambda) Euclidean algorithm.

```
(x,y)->{while(y>0)y=x%(x=y);return x}
```

**Update**

- **-7** [16-10-04] Simplified `while` condition

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>41</s> 51 bytes

similar to [my LCM answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/95068#95068):

```
for($d=1+$a=$argv[1];$argv[2]%--$d||$a%$d;);echo$d;
```

loop `$d` down from `$argv[1]` while `$argv[1]/$d` or `$argv[2]/$d` have a remainder.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 51 bytes

49bytes of code + 2 flags (`-pa`)

```perl
$b=pop@F;($_,$b)=(abs$_-$b,$_>$b?$b:$_)while$_-$b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lybYgv8DBzVpDJV5HJUnTViMxqVglXlclSUcl3k4lyV4lyUolXrM8IzMnFSz8/7@JkYKx6b/8gpLM/Lzi/7q@pnoGhgb/dQsSAQ)

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 54 bytes

```perl
sub g{my($a,$b)=@_;$a-$b?g(abs($a-$b),$a>$b?$b:$a):$a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@4NEkhvTq3UkMlUUclSdPWId5aJVFXJck@XSMxqVgDzNbUUUm0AwqpJFmpJGoCce3////yC0oy8/OK/@v6muoZGBoAAA)

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 38 bytes

```
f=(int a,b)->{return b==0?a:f(b,a%b);}
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: @Ricker thanks :) (I'm assuming that stands for programming puzzles code golf)

Answer (score 2):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), 44 bytes

```
(d G(q((a b)(i(l b a)(G b a)(i a(G(s b a)a)b
```

Defines a function `G` that takes two arguments. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8nMq8zJLC74/18jRcFdo1BDI1EhSVMjUyNHIUkhUVPDHUJlKiRquGsUgzmJmkn/geJGhgqGRpr/AQ)

#### Explanation

Since mod is not built into tinylisp, we use a subtraction-based algorithm instead.

(Glossary of tinylisp builtins used: `d` = def, `q` = quote, `i` = if, `l` = less-than, `s` = subtract)

- Define G `(d G` as a function that takes two arguments `(q((a b)`
- If the second argument is smaller `(i(l b a)` then recurse with the arguments swapped `(G b a)`
- Otherwise, if the first argument is nonzero `(i a` then recurse with the new arguments being (larger minus smaller) and (smaller) `(G(s b a)a)`
- Otherwise (the first argument is zero) return the second argument `b`

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 18 bytes

```
wV Ä o a@!UuX «VuX
```

Brute force, tries every integer.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/vzxM4XCLQr5CooNiaGmEwqHVYaUR//8bGyiYGAEA)

Answer (score 2):

## Smalltalk, 29 bytes

```
[(a:=b\\(b:=a))>0]whileTrue.b
```

### Explanation

```
a, b                  two integers given as input
b\\(b:=a)             compute (b mod a) and then assign a to b
a:=b\\(b:=a)          assign the remainder just computed to a
[(...)>0]whileTrue    repeat while the reminder a is > 0 (stop otherwise)
b                     return b (the gcd) - dot is a sentence separator
```

Comment: Feel free to expand your answer by including an explanation and a link to an online interpreter. Not everyone here knows Smalltalk. When your answers are short and just code, they show in the "Low Quality Posts" queue and users have to review them. Take a look at answers by other users to see some examples.

Comment: @mbomb007 Done. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 22 bytes

```
&&:#v_\.@
p00:<^:\g00%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/X03NSrksPkbPgavAwMDKJs4qJt3AQPX/f2MDLhMjLgA)

Doesn't beat Jo King's answer, but I already spent the time creating this answer before seeing their solution.  C'est la vie.  Uses the same Euclidean Algorithm as most answers.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-h`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 5 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Input as an array.

```
mâ rf
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWg&code=beIgcmY&input=WzEwMSwyMDJd)

```
mâ rf     :Implicit input of integer array
m         :Map
 â        :  Divisors
   r      :Reduce by
    f     :  Filtering, keeping only those elements in the first array that also appear in the second
          :Implicit output of last element
```

Answer (score 2):

## APL (NARS2000), 11 chars, 20 bytes

```
{×/(π⍺)∩π⍵}
```

**Examples:**

```
      28{×/(π⍺)∩π⍵}144
4
      69{×/(π⍺)∩π⍵}25
1
```

**Why it works:**

Function `π`, when applied monadically, breaks down argument into prime factors. `(π⍺)∩π⍵` gives intersection of prime factors of left and right argument. `×/` multiplies prime factors in the intersection, giving the largest divisor common to `⍺` and `w`. In case `⍺` and `w` are co-prime then reducing empty intersection would give `1`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 58 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:max(n for n in range(1,max(a,b)+1)if a%n+b%n<1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PycxNyklUSFRJ8kqN7FCI08hLb9IIU8hM0@hKDEvPVXDUAckDJTW1DbUzExTSFTN005SzbMx1PyfpmFooPkfAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 11 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

```
{(|⊣)⍟}
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAge/CdlagofPCdlYriiqMp4o2f8J2VqPCdlal9CgoKPiAw4oC/NuKAvzMw4oC/MTXigL834oC/NjnigL8yMeKAvzE2OeKAvzIw4oC/MTAxICjiiY3ii4hGKcKoIDLigL8w4oC/NDLigL8xNOKAvzfigL8yNeKAvzEy4oC/MTIz4oC/MTQy4oC/MjAy)

3 bytes shorter and a lot less efficient than the version provided on BQNcrate: [`{(|⍟(>⟜0)⊣)}`](https://mlochbaum.github.io/bqncrate/?q=gcd)

This is a dyadic function with arguments  and .

With left argument  and starting with  as a right argument, call `(|⊣)`  times, updating the right argument with the return value.  refers to the full function and `|⊣` does a recursive call with `|` ( mod ) as left and  as right argument.

It would be enough to call the inner function just once if  is positive, and not at all if  is 0, but `⍟(×)` is just too long.

Answer (score 2):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 39 bytes

```rust
|a,b|(1..=a+b).rev().find(|i|a%i+b%i<1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZDRCsIwDEXf9xXxQWi1lLVzE1G/REQ6bKGgVbuqD9Zvn@kQ3RZSCCc3NyX@3oTWODgr6wiFVwYYJx3AwBbaqFgdieB8q@Y15V4/COXGuiOJNqqpnddTuxG0TUPrrJs1Fw8Exxgo1zy1p2Ad7LpWCpIzkJiU/VHFAGnVRwWChRxBUTIQC3x9uGSQcuC3wgXlSCcFAnQsBo5JKmQx1uZp0fibIkcLmSPG6tvYcxu0/x0uhWoa7cNB3ybEpENQfndPr66EMph9b7Lu1O/s3X4A)

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, 48 bytes

```
$=((r,a)=>{for(;a;){var e=a;a=r%a,r=e}return r})
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to test this - when I run it [like this](https://tio.run/##FcpBCoAgEAXQq7gJFCyi2ond5WMWhTgxmpvo7FbbxztQkBzvZ24jLb7WAhawkjWUne@VWBoY9WuxMOzzxfEL3ECzLY@pjmKi4LtAm4Qcey2mQan6Ag) it doesn't terminate - how should I run this?

Comment: @hyper-neutrino its a function so you need to run it with the parameters being two numbers that you want to find the GCD of. E.g a(2,5)

Comment: In my linked example I tried running `a(30, 42)` and it didn't work. Perhaps the variable name duplication is causing some issues here?

Comment: @hyper-neutrino are you console logging it

Comment: [this](https://tio.run/##FcpBCoAgEAXQq7gJFCyi2ond5WMWhTgxmpvo7FbbxztQkBzvZ24jLb7WAhawkjWUne@VWBoY9WuxMOzzxfEL3ECzLY@pjmKi4LtAm4Qcey2mQan6Ag) is how I am running it. I also tried doing `a(30, 42)` in my console and it terminated without outputting anything. What version of JavaScript is this? Mine might be out of date.

Comment: @hyper-neutrino I have rewritten it and now it should be supported by any version above ES6. It works completely fine for me and I've tried two different computers

Answer (score 2):

## [Nibbles](https://nibbles.golf), 5 bytes (10 nibbles)

```
`;~$@@$_@%
```

### Verbose

```
`;   # Recursive function
  ~ $ @   # Call it with the first two command-line arguments (m,n)
  @   # Recurse if n is truthy
  $   # Base case = m
  _ @ %   # Recursive case = gcd(n, m mod n)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 13 bytes

```
∴ƛ□$%∑¬;¦:Gḟ›
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLiiLTGm+KWoSQl4oiRwqw7wqY6R+G4n+KAuiIsIiIsIjIxXG4xMiJd)

Thanks to *@Fhuvi* for pointing out a bug.

**Explanation:**

```python
∴ƛ□$%∑¬;¦:Gḟ›  # Implicit inputs
∴              # Maximum input
 ƛ     ;       # Map over range(1, ^ + 1):
  □$           #  Push input list and swap
    %∑         #  Sum of each input mod the number
      ¬        #  Equals 0?
        ¦      # Cumulative sums of the list
         :G    # Maximum of that list
           ḟ   # Index of that in the cumulative sums
            ›  # Plus one to account for 0-indexing
               # Implicit output
```

Comment: "You are not allowed to use built-ins that compute either the GCD or the LCM (least common multiple)."

Comment: Yeah, I just saw that. Sorry.

Comment: Sorry if this adds more work (or bytes), but it seems to not work properly if the first parameter is zero ^^'

Comment: @Fhuvi thanks for noticing. That's easily fixed, by adding a `∴` at the start.

Answer (score 2):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 30 bytes

Takes a list of two numbers

```
until(min<1;[max-min,min])|max
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jcu7CoAwDIXh3afIqFAhiTdE36R0cKyoICg4@O41pw6FL4e/65nSfVxxK/d4zDL5fXlqo7MXqteulDw7IlKiUPge5MwGc6ugdEZpwQHB8LejWTtQBcHfYhZtsHL@pljZCmUNHw)

Answer (score 2):

## [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 37

Recursive:

```
g(){ (($2))&&g $2 $[$1%$2]||echo $1;}
```

But for making useful function, I prefer assigning variable in order to avoid forks. So I will prefer this `for` loop:

```
for((i=$1,l=$2;l;k=l,l=i%l,i=k)){ :;}
```

Note: both routines use 37 characters!

**Test cases**

```
for pair in 0\ 2 6\ 0 30\ 42 15\ 14 7\ 7 69\ 25 21\ 12 169\ 123 20\ 142 101\ 202;do
    printf '%4d %4d => %3d\n' $pair $(g $pair)
done
   0    2 =>   2
   6    0 =>   6
  30   42 =>   6
  15   14 =>   1
   7    7 =>   7
  69   25 =>   1
  21   12 =>   3
 169  123 =>   1
  20  142 =>   2
 101  202 => 101
```

#### As a dedicated function:

```
gcd() {
    if [[ $1 == -v ]];then local -n i=$2;shift 2;else local i;fi
    local l=$2 k
    for((i=$1;l;k=l,l=i%l,i=k)){ :;}
    [[ ${i@A} != i=* ]] || echo "$i"
}
```

**Test cases**

```
for pair in 0:2 6:0 30:42 15:14 7:7 69:25 21:12 169:123 20:142 101:202;do
    IFS=: read -ra vals <<<$pair
    gcd -v res ${vals[@]}
    printf '    %4d %4d => %3d\n' ${vals[@]} $res
done
   0    2 =>   2
   6    0 =>   6
  30   42 =>   6
  15   14 =>   1
   7    7 =>   7
  69   25 =>   1
  21   12 =>   3
 169  123 =>   1
  20  142 =>   2
 101  202 => 101
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com), 44 bytes

```
f(l)=[i0^{mod(l,i).max}fori=[1...l.max]].max
```

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jg8j57ejb5)

Input is a list of two integers. It won't work if at least one of the inputs is greater than 10000 because of list length limits, so this is possibly non-competing.

Answer (score 2):

## [Piet](https://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html) + [ascii-piet](https://github.com/dloscutoff/ascii-piet), 42 bytes (2×21=42 codels)

```
qbdijbrlkumldqralckkB   jj   s??venvfff bb
```

[Try Piet online!](https://piet.bubbler.one/#eJw9jd0KgzAMRl-l5PoTklh_6quoF8N1IDgnOK_G3n2pU8MHOTlJ6YeG1z1S07YeYlEIo06oKBFQQMTAfDJSJi7MBzvp0Yr1PXV6dA45pN4DqVCllp8J-y--70FrXKihLMsINI1PY-V_mYjrQM3jNq0RNM7L9rY1O-1mu-_m0vFBOTt_2eC0OFjZybUQFqes9P0BlJ827Q)

[image]

Comment: Very obvious [48 bytes](https://piet.bubbler.one/#eJw9jMEKg0AMRH9lyXmEJKur66-oh2K3IFgr2J5K_73Zag0DecxM8qbxcU3Udh1DAhoEiMKYjaWEmhFRQWRPsmM948r8aJUBndiOCHvDqMm38ZCHND9BatR5-b_yef4wgLa0UktFURBonu7GyvuYkbaR2ttl3hJoWtbX02J22i_W75fg-CDPrjzd6LQ6WNnJGQiLU1b6fAEB_jlg) that I noticed at first glance.

Comment: [42 bytes](https://piet.bubbler.one/#eJw9jd0KgzAMRl-l5PoTklh_6quoF8N1IDgnOK_G3n2pU8MHOTlJ6YeG1z1S07YeYlEIo06oKBFQQMTAfDJSJi7MBzvp0Yr1PXV6dA45pN4DqVCllp8J-y--70FrXKihLMsINI1PY-V_mYjrQM3jNq0RNM7L9rY1O-1mu-_m0vFBOTt_2eC0OFjZybUQFqes9P0BlJ827Q)

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 19 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 15.64 bytes

```
~e1+I$S0=Ez(DMsAh1+
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhab61INtT1Vgg1sXas0XHyLHTMMtSEyC2CUkSGXoRGEAwA)

Thanks to *@Fhuvi* for pointing out a bug.

##### Explanation

```python
~e1+I$S0=Ez(DMsAh1+  # Implicit input
~                    # First non-zero input
 e       E           # Map over the range:
  1+                 #  Increment
    I$               #  Mod the input list
      S0=            #  Sum equals 0
          z(         # Cumulative sums
            DM       # Maximum
              sAh    # Index of this in the list
                 1+  # Incremented
                     # Implicit output
```

Old one which didn't work for 0:

```python
eI$S0=Ez(DMsAh  # Implicit input
e     E         # Map over range:
 I$             #  This number mod the input list
   S0=          #  Sum equals 0
       z(       # Cumulative sums
         DM     # Maximum
           sAh  # Index of this in the list
                # Implicit output
```

Comment: Sorry again, but it seems to not work properly if one of the parameters is zero ^^'

Comment: @Fhuvi fixed at the cost of 5 characters

Answer (score 2):

### C, 23 bytes

```
f(x,y){x=x?f(y%x,x):y;}
```

Essentially Euclid's algorithm in a ternary expression with recursion.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 27 bytes

```
If[#<1,#2,#0[#2,#~Mod~#2]]&
```

Not much to see here.

Answer (score 1):

### Seriously, 23 bytes

```
,,;'XQ1╟";(%{}"f3δI£ƒkΣ
```

This makes use of the `Q`uine command, which is currently the only sane way to do recursion.

[Try it online!](http://seriously.tryitonline.net/#code=LCw7J1hRMeKVnyI7KCV7fcaSImYzzrRJwqPGkmvOow&input=NgoyMQ)

Explanation:

```
,,;'XQ1╟";(%{}"f3δI£ƒkΣ
,,;                      get a and b inputs, duplicate b
   'X                    push "x"
     Q1╟                 push a list containing the program's source code as the singular element
        ";(%{}"f         push the string ";(%{}".format(source_code) (essentially "gcd(b, a % b)")
                3δ       bring the second copy of b to TOS
                  I      if: pop b, recursive call, and "X", and push recursive call if b != 0 else "X"
                   £ƒ    call the string as a function
                     kΣ  sum stack elements (without this, the stack contains the gcd and possibly several 0's)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [RETURN](https://github.com/molarmanful/RETURN), 16 bytes

```
[$[\¤÷%G][\]?]=G
```

<kbd>[Try it here.](http://molarmanful.github.io/RETURN/)</kbd>

Recursive operator implementation of Euclid's algorithm. Leaves result on top of stack. Usage:

```
[$[\¤÷%G][\]?]=G21 12G
```

## Explanation

```
[            ]=G  Define operator G
 $                Check if b is truthy
  [     ][ ]?     Conditional
   \¤               If so, create pattern [b a b] on stack
     ÷%             Mod top 2 items
       G            Recurse
          \         Otherwise, swap top 2 items
```

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL, 147 Bytes

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/45db0/1)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE PROC G @ INT,@B INT,@C INT OUT AS BEGIN IF @<@B EXEC G @B,@,@C OUT ELSE IF @B>0 BEGIN SELECT @=@%@B EXEC G @B,@,@C OUT END ELSE SET @C=@ END
```

**Testing**:

Use something like this to generate each set of results:

```
DECLARE @A INT,@B INT,@EXP INT,@RES INT
  SELECT @A=0,@B=2,@EXP=2
  EXEC G @A,@B,@RES OUT
  SELECT @A A,@B B,@EXP EXPECTED,@RES RESULT
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/45db0/1/0)**:

```
|  A  |  B  | EXPECTED | RESULT |
|-----|-----|----------|--------|
|   0 |   2 |        2 |      2 |
|   6 |   0 |        6 |      6 |
|  30 |  42 |        6 |      6 |
|  15 |  14 |        1 |      1 |
|   7 |   7 |        7 |      7 |
|  69 |  25 |        1 |      1 |
|  21 |  12 |        3 |      3 |
|  20 | 142 |        2 |      2 |
| 101 | 202 |      101 |    101 |
```

Answer (score 1):

## Oracle SQL 11.2, 108 Bytes

```
CREATE PROCEDURE G(A INT,B INT,C OUT INT)AS BEGIN IF A>0 THEN G(LEAST(A,B),ABS(A-B),C);ELSE C:=B;END IF;END;
```

**Testing**:

```
CREATE FUNCTION testHelper(A INT,B INT) RETURN INT
AS
  C INT;
BEGIN
  G(A,B,C);
  RETURN C;
END;
/

WITH tests( A, B, Expected ) AS (
  SELECT   0,  2,  2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   6,  0,  6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  30, 42,  6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  15, 14,  1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   7,  7,  7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  69, 25,  1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  21, 12,  3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 169,123,  1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  20,142,  2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 101,202,101 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT t.*,testHelper(A,B) AS "RESULT"
FROM   tests t;
```

**Output**:

```
         A          B   EXPECTED     RESULT
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         0          2          2          2 
         6          0          6          6 
        30         42          6          6 
        15         14          1          1 
         7          7          7          7 
        69         25          1          1 
        21         12          3          3 
       169        123          1          1 
        20        142          2          2 
       101        202        101        101
```

Answer (score 1):

## J, <s>15</s> 14 bytes

```
[`(|$:[)@.(]*)
```

Uses Euclid's algorithm.

### Usage

```
   f =: [`(|$:[)@.(]*)
   30 f 42
6
   42 f 30
6
   169 f 123
1
```

### Explanation

```
[`(|$:[)@.(]*)  Input: a, b
           ]*   Get sign(b)
                If sign(n) = 0
[                 Return a
                Else
   |              Get b mod a
      [           Get a
    $:            Call recursively on (b mod a, a)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 7, 42 bytes

```
int c(int a,int b){return b>0?c(b,a%b):a;}
```

**Ungolfed & test cases:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/KFfrAD)

```
class M{
  static int c(int a, int b){
    return b > 0
            ? c(b, a%b)
            : a;
  }

  public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.println(c(0, 2));
    System.out.println(c(6, 0));
    System.out.println(c(30, 42));
    System.out.println(c(15, 14));
    System.out.println(c(7, 7));
    System.out.println(c(69, 25));
    System.out.println(c(21, 12));
    System.out.println(c(169, 123));
    System.out.println(c(20, 142));
    System.out.println(c(101, 202));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2
6
6
1
7
1
3
1
2
101
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-93](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge), 21 bytes

```
&&:v_.@
00:_^#:%g00\p
```

[Try it Online](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/X03Nqixez4HLwMAqPk7ZSjXdwCCm4P9/Q2MDBTNTAA)

Yet another Euclidean algorithm

Answer (score 1):

## MACHINE LANGUAGE(X86, 32 bit), 19 bytes

```
0000079C  8B442404          mov eax,[esp+0x4]
000007A0  8B4C2408          mov ecx,[esp+0x8]
000007A4  E308              jecxz 0x7ae
000007A6  31D2              xor edx,edx
000007A8  F7F1              div ecx
000007AA  92                xchg eax,edx
000007AB  91                xchg eax,ecx
000007AC  EBF6              jmp short 0x7a4
000007AE  C3                ret
000007AF
```

7AFh-79Ch=13h=19d (see other x86 solution too).Below assembly with the function,
but for me gcd(a,b) if a or b is 0 has to return -1 error...

```
; nasmw -fobj  this.asm
; bcc32 -v  file.c this.obj
section _DATA use32 public class=DATA
global _gcda
section _TEXT use32 public class=CODE


_gcda:    
      mov     eax,  dword[esp+  4]
      mov     ecx,  dword[esp+  8]
.1:   JECXZ   .z
      xor     edx,  edx
      div     ecx
      xchg    eax,  edx
      xchg    eax,  ecx
      jmp     short  .1
.z:       
      ret
```

this is the C function for test, that call the gcda() function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
unsigned v0[]={30,15,7,69,21,169, 20,101,0,6,1,0};
unsigned v1[]={42,14,7,25,12,123,142,202,2,0,2,0};
unsigned gcda(unsigned,unsigned);

main(void)
{int  i;
 for(i=0;v0[i]||v1[i];++i)
    printf("gcd(%u,%u)=%u\n",v0[i],v1[i],gcda(v0[i],v1[i]));    
 return 0;
}
```

results:

```
gcd(30,42)=6
gcd(15,14)=1
gcd(7,7)=7
gcd(69,25)=1
gcd(21,12)=3
gcd(169,123)=1
gcd(20,142)=2
gcd(101,202)=101
gcd(0,2)=2
gcd(6,0)=6
gcd(1,2)=1
```

Comment: The loop is the same as the unsigned 32-bit version described in [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77364/30206), except without the `inc`/loop` optimization (3 bytes in 32-bit mode vs. 2+2=4 for JECXZ/JMP), so it's safer with a 0 input. Plus loading args from the stack, instead of using a better calling convention like GCC's `__attribute__((regparm(3)))` (EAX, EDX, ECX in that order).  Even for stack args, you could do 3x pop, then 3x push to put things back (including the return address), leaving values in regs in 6 bytes instead of 8 for 2x 4 (mov_opcode + modrm + sib + disp8)

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, 9 bytes

```
V?ßVU%V:U
```

[Run it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=Vj/fVlUlVjpV&input=MzAgNDI=)

**8 bytes** if we can reverse the order of the input:

```
?ßV%UU:V
```

[Run it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=P99WJVVVOlY=&input=NDIgMzA=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ink](https://github.com/inkle/ink), 29 bytes

```
=i(a,b)
{b:->i(b,a%b)}{a}->->
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYw7CsAgEER77xGIMMLu5iMJxJOk0U4CuUDw7EYrt3zzZia/T3UhzwSxLpjbdNhBAxbCqhxv4HWgh1e7A7INFAbrZdMsi/LUrnSBGEI9qFeeI5I1Xzq7SYhTsuWLxYVm6w8)

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), 13 chars, 26 bytes

```
{⍵<1:⍺⋄⍵∇⍵∣⍺}
```

test:

```
  g←{⍵<1:⍺⋄⍵∇⍵∣⍺}
  30 g 42
6
  42 g 30
6
  15 g 14
1
  7 g 7
7
  69 g 25
1
  0 g 2
2
  6 g 0
6
```

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 39 bytes

```
{for(x=$1>$2?$1:$2;$1%x||$2%x;)--x}$0=x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY2xDsIwDER3f4UHV4Khku/SpoIq5VtYWBiQWIhE@fa0QOLt6d2dr697Ke/b43nIybAYL4azcTZ0eV2NXZ6PfZ8/5imX4kr9XlqUEtUbRAmuAxtgVAx/gEw6tdgk8aQcmyEUtRMEuwJDNb4PsP6BQ@n8GYds)

Does require that 1 of the inputs be positive. Nothing fancy, but I don't see another `AWK` solution.

Answer (score 1):

### Perl 6, 28 bytes

```
my&f={$^b??f($b,$^a%$b)!!$a}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 52 bytes

```forth
: f begin 2dup max -rot min tuck mod ?dup 0= until ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//WymkKSSlpmfmKRillBYo5CZWKOgW5Zco5AJFSkqTsxVy81MU7EFSBrYKpXklmTkK1v//AwA)

Uses Euclidean Algorithm [repeatedly call larger % smaller until result is 0]

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f               \ start a new word definition
  begin           \ start and indefinite loop
    2dup          \ duplicate arguments
    max -rot min  \ reorder arguments so the smaller is on top
    tuck          \ make a copy of the smaller argument and move it behind the larger
    mod ?dup 0=   \ get the modulo of the two arguments, then duplicate and check if it is 0
  until           \ end the loop if it is
;                 \ end the word definition
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ral](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Ral), <s>45</s> 37 bytes

```
,:,+0=0*/-:1+1:+1+:+:1=?0*+0*/:0=1*?.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZHBb4MgFMbv/BUv3UEUtLDuxMbMjj21WXYzZqGKKYlaom23Zdnf7qC10V5eHr/v4/EB9ue4P7Sr4QHe4F3VYNqj7mynXYXq0MHHeoPWslbNrlTCidi09nTEYYg2I4WzsJ1XziEqdQXdqcVFKBAU1NCeNjIrLpMKN9uX6tIFjJNYLCNJk/QzyCmjWU5//xDYaWyfKGt1W/rJsL2F6BN7sDh0c3rQda@BIfjam1qDean1eDYYWkpDOC0yk/tlBeX11EBY7NOW7gpXLmVAPN3ikGzxHMcjju@xCISSDj1brK5l0pZOozuv0pljN3NE0@4mU7mjyr9MM15m5pQ3p/f5ZpKoT7a@S5UEYoPvg6aBfwpQ416PXffKhJGN@saMuuTI/9disRiooIRJFi1jwQkXhBNBBJcpi4iDgkkepcngnOGwYujp8R8) (inputs on separate lines)

Commented:

```
,:,                  Input a and b
+0=                  Add a to b
                   Loop:
0*/-                 Subtract b from a
:1+1:+1+:+:1=?       Continue if a >= 0
0*+                  Add b to a
0*/:0=               Swap a and b
1*?                  Continue if b > 0
.                    Print a
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 29 bytes

```sh
(($1))&&$0 $[$2%$1] $1||<<<$2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYo7DoAwDEN3TuEhoHaL0wJC6k0QM@xsfM5eUhY/@dnXedQ9xLuGIIxxGEQhq1gv3CB8nlKKWH27HQrznKCeSZFb4whm54y5bQtsdBrBf3VBS82o/36l9GL1Aw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
GıḊp;ṡDGȮ⁺
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWm9yPbHy4o6vA-uHOhS7uJ9Y9aty1pDgpuRgqvWCZoamOgpEhhAcA)

Port of my Vyxal answer.

##### Explanation

```python
GıḊp;ṡDGȮ⁺  # Implicit input
Gı  ;       # Map over (the one-range of) the higher number:
  Ḋ         #  Is each input divisible by this number?
   p        #  Are both true?
     ṡ      # Cumulative sums of this list
      DG    # Without popping, push the maximum
        Ȯ⁺  # 1-based index of the maximum
            # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `G`, 37 [bits<sup>v1</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 4.625 bytes

```
vKƒ↔∨
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyJHfj0iLCIiLCJ2S8aS4oaU4oioIiwiIiwiWzAsIDJdICAgID0+IDJcbls2LCAwXSAgICA9PiA2XG5bMzAsIDQyXSAgPT4gNlxuWzE1LCAxNF0gICA9PiAxXG5bNywgN10gICA9PiA3XG5bNjksIDI1XSAgPT4gMVxuWzIxLCAxMl0gID0+IDNcblsxNjksIDEyM10gPT4gMVxuWzIwLCAxNDJdID0+IDJcblsxMDEsIDIwMl0gPT4gMTAxIl0=)

Why use ranges and sums when a more logical approach is shorter :p

Takes input as a list of numbers.

### Explained

```
vKƒ↔∨
vK      # Get the divisors of each number
  ƒ↔    # reduce by set intersection. This will either give a list of shared divisors or an empty list. You only get an empty list if there is a 0 in the input. 
     ∨  # logical or with the input, getting the first truthy value. If there's a 0 in the input, this returns the input list
# The G flag gets the biggest of either the shared factors or the input list if there's a 0.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 5 bytes

```
ṀRᶠ¦Ṁ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6Fmse7mwIerhtwaFlQMaS4qTkYqjEgpt-0QY6RrFc0WY6BkDS2EDHBMQzNNUxNAHS5jrmIDlLHSNTIG1kqGMIlgUKGBoZg0QMgOrAQgaGOkYGRrEQYwE)

Takes a list of two numbers as input.

```
ṀRᶠ¦Ṁ
Ṁ       Maximum of the input
 R      Range from 1 to that
  ᶠ     Filter by the following function:
   ¦      Check that it divides both numbers in the input
    Ṁ   Maximum of the resulting list
```

---

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 6 bytes

```
ʷ{$ᵉ%Z
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6FitPba9Webi1UzVqSXFScjFUdMFNKwMFIy4zBQMuYwMFEyMuQ1MFQxMucwVzLjNLBSNTLiNDBUOgKJBjaGTMZWQAlAVyDQwVjAyMIEYAAA)

Using the Euclidean algorithm.

```
ʷ{$ᵉ%Z
ʷ{      Apply the following function repeatedly until it fails:
          Let the stack be a, b
  $       a, b -> b, a
   ᵉ%     b, a -> b, a % b
     Z    Check that b is not zero
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 2 bytes

```
iE
```

[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=iE&input=3%0A6&debug=0)

Input as integer on two separate lines. Just uses a builtin.

Comment: Haha, I like it.

Comment: If you change the input format, `iF` also works. In addition, I think `M?HgH%GHG` is the shortest no-builtin way of doing this.

Comment: I think the question disallows using a GCD builtin.