# Adding fractions

Tags: code-golf, math, rational-numbers

Write a program or a function that takes two non-empty lists of the same length as input and does the following:

- uses elements of first list to get numerators,
- uses elements of the second list to get denominators,
- displays resulting fractions after simplification `(2/4=>1/2)`, separated by "+"s,
- displays "=" and result of addition after last fraction.

### Example:

#### Input

```
[1, 2, 3, 3, 6]
[2, 9, 3, 2, 4]
```

#### Output

```
1/2+2/9+1+3/2+3/2=85/18
```

### About rules

- elements of lists will be positive integers,
- elements can be separated by spaces, eg: `1/2 + 2/9 + 1 + 3/2 + 3/2 = 85/18` is ok,
- trailing newline is allowed,
- lists can be taken in other formats than above, eg.: `(1 2 3 3 6)` or `{1;2;3;3;6}`, etc.,
- `1` can be expressed as `1/1`,
- instead of printing you can return appropriate string,
- you do not need to handle wrong input,
- **shortest code wins**.

Comment: What range of values does it have to support?

Comment: @BradGilbertb2gills I would say at least -30 000 to 30 000, but then I don't know whether it would be extra problem for some languages. So maybe just standard integer range of your language of choice.

Comment: @PrzemysławP saying "standard integer range of your language of choice" is not a good idea, some languages have standard integer as booleans

Comment: Thank you! @BradGilbertb2gills Then at least -30 000 to 30 000.

Comment: Can we get fractions as `[1, 2] [2, 9] [3, 3] ...` instead?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire No, sorry!

Comment: The standard integer range for Perl 6 is infinite, but the default range for denominators of Rationals is `uint64.Range.max`. So I was asking if I had to convert them all to FatRats instead.

Comment: @BradGilbertb2gills Sorry if I caused confusion - my second comment applies: -30 000 to 30 000.

Comment: can i concatenate the both lists as `[1, 2, 3, 3, 6, 2, 9, 3, 2, 4]` ?

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista The input should be taken as two lists. After that you can obviously concatenate them.

Comment: Are the inputs going to be positive?

Comment: @Dennis Not always.

Comment: That should be reflected in the test cases.

Comment: @Dennis You are right. I'll add one more test case.

Comment: Can we assume the lists will always have at least two elements each?

Comment: @ScottMilner Yes.

Comment: @Dennis It looks like pretty much every solution assumed it's always positive integers so I think it's better to say that input should be only positive integer. Sorry for confusion:/

Comment: @BradGilbertb2gills Sorry again, but seeing that many people assumed input should be positive integers I think it's better to say that minimal supported range would be 1-30 000. Again, sorry for confusion:/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [M](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/m), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
÷µFj”+;”=;S
```

This is a dyadic link. Due to a bug, it doesn't work as a full program. `F` is also required due to a bug.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/3///D2Q1vdsh41zNW2BhK21sH/DXWMdIyB0OzwciMdSyDDSMfkPwA)

#### How it works

```
÷µFj”+;”=;S  Dyadic link. Left argument: N. Right argument: D

÷            Perform vectorized division, yielding an array of fractions (R).
 µ           Begin a new, monadic chain. Argument: R
  F          Flatten R. R is already flat, but j is buggy and has side effects.
   j”+       Join R, separating by '+'.
      ;”=    Append '='.
         ;S  Append the sum of R.
```

Comment: I like how more than a quarter of the program is to append the '='.  :)

Answer (score 7):

## Ruby 2.4, <s>54</s> 53 characters

```ruby
->n,d{a=n.zip(d).map{|n,d|n.to_r/d};a*?++"=#{a.sum}"}
```

Thanks to:

- [Value Ink](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52194/value-ink) for the Ruby 2.4 specific version (-3 characters)
- [Value Ink](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52194/value-ink) for optimizing the `Rational` initialization (-1 character)

#### Ruby, <s>58</s> <s>57</s> 56 characters

```ruby
->n,d{t=0;n.zip(d).map{|n,d|t+=r=n.to_r/d;r}*?++"=#{t}"}
```

Sample run:

```
irb(main):001:0> puts ->n,d{t=0;n.zip(d).map{|n,d|t+=r=n.to_r/d;r}*?++"=#{t}"}[[1, 2, 3, 3, 6], [2, 9, 3, 2, 4]]
1/2+2/9+1/1+3/2+3/2=85/18
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#S7P9r2uXp5NSXWJrYJ2nV5VZoJGiqZebWFBdAxStKdG2LbLN0yvJjy/ST7EuqtWy19ZWslWuLqlVqv1fUFpSrJAWHW2oo2Cko2AMRmaxOgrRQJ4lmAdkmMTG/gcA)

Comment: `a=n.zip(d).map{|f|(f*?/).to_r};a*?++"=#{a.sum}"` in Ruby 2.4 saves you 3 bytes.

Comment: Thanks @ValueInk. I suspected that may be possible, just had no 2.4 neither locally nor on TIO.

Comment: Yeah, I installed 2.4 specifically so I could test out solutions with `sum` haha. Also I just remembered that `.map{|i,j|i.to_r/j}` is shorter by 1 byte

Comment: Doh. I tried various approaches through `.to_f` and division, but didn't thought to dividing `Rational` with `Fixnum`. Thanks again, @ValueInk.

Answer (score 6):

### Mathematica, 33 bytes

```
Row@{Row[#/#2,"+"],"=",Tr[#/#2]}&
```

input

> [{1, 2, 3, 3, 6}, {2, 9, 3, 2, 4}]

Comment: Isn't `Row@@{#/#2,"+"}` the same as `Row[#/#2,"+"]`?

Comment: yes! you are right!

Comment: Fantastic! I didn't realize `Row` was so convenient for things like this :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 104 bytes

9 bytes thanks to Felipe Nardi Batista.

```python
from fractions import*
def f(*t):c=[Fraction(*t)for t in zip(*t)];print('+'.join(map(str,c)),'=',sum(c))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#LcnLCsIwEIXhvU8xu0zqIHhBsNKtLxG6KNGBEXIhGTe@fEyLcBb/x2lcUgAui1dJsYKEnIoOu@eLgXFQO/rJPf73ak4FFCTCV/Lq@Z6LREWzN4d3kohhyVi1kLeWzGSofgL2bozuSHAiOG@7zgSu67apx2W27Qc)

Comment: [golfed a bit](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#LYm7CgIxEAB7v2K7bHJB8IGgcq0/EVIc0YWIebBZG38@xkOYYobpxCUB8RIkltwgplpYzOb@ICA0L30Js7v9NxrRVBgEYoZPrL/vr5VjFjWp7bPEjGmp2IRt0HpSs5qGY3snHN0J3c7C3sJh5eQtuFHntYYcve5f)

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista muito.

Comment: change `+'='+str(sum(c))` to `,'=',sum(c)`

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista Thanks, also I've used Python 3 here (based on personal preference).

Comment: [You can save a lot of bytes by switching to Python 2](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#LYpLCgJBDET3niK7TsYg@EFwZLZeYpjF0BpooT@k4/nbdhBqUe9VNdEcQXT1FnKqEGLJasPu@RIQHIxGP8W14OP/4K7uRUMyt3eHdw4Jf3M1ZU/EbnJcPxE9NcH5yHBiOG@5Lgxzp9tGvVwWal8)

Comment: At the cost of 5 bytes you can stay at python3: `def f(*t):c=[*map(Fraction,*t)];print('+'.join(map(str,c)),'=',sum(c))` (93 bytes)

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>77</s>  73 bytes

```perl6
{join('+',($/=[@^a Z/ @^b]).map:{.nude.join('/')})~"="~$/.sum.nude.join('/')}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#Ky1OVSgz00u25sqtVFBLzk9JVbD9X52Vn5mnoa6trqOhom8b7RCXqBClr@AQlxSrqZebWGBVrZdXmpKqB1Glr65Zq1mnZKtUp6KvV1yaiy73v6C0RAFksAaXgkK0oY6CkY6CMRiZxeqAhIB8SzAfyDCJ5dK0/g8A)

```perl6
{($/=[@^a Z/@^b])».nude».join('/').join('+')~'='~$/.sum.nude.join('/')}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#Ky1OVSgz00u25sqtVFBLzk9JVbD9X62hom8b7RCXqBCl7xCXFKt5aLdeXmlKKpDKys/M01DXV9eEsrTVNevUbdXrVPT1iktzwaoQamr/F5SWKIAM1eBSUIg21FEw0lEwBiOzWB2QEJBvCeYDGSaxXJrW/wE)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{  # bare block lambda with two placeholder params ｢@a｣ and ｢@b｣

  (
    $/ = [              # store as an array in ｢$/｣ for later use

      @^a Z/ @^b        # zip divide the two inputs (declares them)

    ]

  )».nude\              # get list of NUmerators and DEnominators
  ».join('/')           # join the numerators and denominators with ｢/｣

  .join('+')            # join that list with ｢+｣

  ~
  '='                   # concat with ｢=｣
  ~

  $/.sum.nude.join('/') # get the result and represent as fraction
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Clojure, 71 bytes

```
#(let[S(map / % %2)](apply str(concat(interpose '+ S)['=(apply + S)])))
```

Yay for built-in fractions!

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 61 bytes

```
t=#~ToString~InputForm&;Riffle[t/@#,"+"]<>"="<>t@Tr@#&[#/#2]&
```

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 111 bytes

Takes the lists in currying syntax `(a)(b)`.

```js
let f =

a=>b=>a.map((v,i)=>F(A=v,B=b[i],N=N*B+v*D,D*=B),N=0,D=1,F=(a,b)=>b?F(b,a%b):A/a+'/'+B/a).join`+`+'='+F(A=N,B=D)

console.log(f([1, 2, 3, 3, 6])([2, 9, 3, 2, 4]))
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 225 bytes

```
int c(int a,int b){return b>0?c(b,a%b):a;}
(N,D)->{int n=0,d=1,i=0,g;String s="";for(;i<N.length;g=g(N[i],D[i]),N[i]/=g,D[i]/=g,s+=(i>0?"+":"")+N[i]+"/"+D[i],n=n*D[i]+N[i]*d,d*=D[i++],g=g(n,d),n/=g,d/=g);return s+"="+n+"/"+d;}
```

`N` and `D` are both `int[]`, contextualized.

I reused [Kevin Cruijssen's GCD function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/92494/16236).

[See it and test it online!](http://ideone.com/jb3LJs)

Answer (score 2):

### [Julia](https://julialang.org/) v0.4+, <s>66</s> 53 bytes

*-13 bytes thanks to Dennis*

```
a^b=replace(join(a.//b,"+")"=$(sum(a.//b))","//","/")
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUz8/z8vLsW2KLUgJzE5VSMrPzNPI09PXz9FR0lbSVPJVkWjuDQXIqKpqaSjpK8PIpQ0/xcUZeaV5ORpRBvqGOkYA6FZrEKcQrSRjiWQbaRjEqv5HwA)

Alternately, if fractions can be displayed using `//` rather than `/`, the following works for **35 bytes**:

```
a^b=join(a.//b,'+')"=$(sum(a.//b))"
```

Answer (score 2):

## [setlX](https://randoom.org/Software/SetlX), 103 bytes

```
f:=procedure(a,b){i:=1;l:=[];while(i<=#a){l:=l+[a[i]/b[i]];i+=1;}s:=join(l,"+");return s+"="+eval(s);};
```

Creates a function called `f` where your insert two lists.

ungolfed:

```
f := procedure (a,b) {
    i:=1;
    l:=[];
    while(i<=#a){
        l:=l+[a[i]/b[i]];
        i+=1;
    }
    s:=join(l,"+");
    return s+"="+eval(s);
};
```

with named variables and annotations:
<sub>setlX doesn't provide a comment feature so let's just pretend that we can comment with `%`</sub>

```
f := procedure(firstList,secondList) {
    count := 1;
    list := []; 
    while(count <= #firstList) {
        % calculate every fraction and save it as a list
        list := list + [firstList[count]/secondList[count]];
        count += 1;
    }
    % Seperate every list entry with a plus ([2/3,1] -> "2/3+1")
    str := join(list, "+");
    % eval executes the string above and thus calculates our sum
    return str + "=" + eval(str);
};
```

[image]

Comment: What if #firstList is different from #secondList?

Comment: you mean differnet size? The question states that first list is used by enumerator and wrong input can be ingored

Comment: but other than that: if the second list is longer, the remaining entries will be ignored. If the list is shorter a runtime error will occur.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>35</s> 34 bytes

```
‚øvyy¿÷'/ý'+}¨'=¹.¿©¹÷²*O®‚D¿÷'/ýJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@/@oYdbhHWWVlYf2H96urn94r7p27aEV6raHduod2n9o5aGdh7cf2qTlf2gdUJ0LTI3X///RRjoKljoKxjoKQIZJLFe0IZhlDEZmsQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 31 bytes

```
,:gj”/
ṙJ$ṖP×Sç⁸P¤,ç@"j”+$¥Ṛj”=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@69jlZ71qGGuPtfDnTO9VB7unBZweHrw4eWPGncEHFqic3i5gxJIWlvl0NKHO2eBmLb///@PNtJRsNRRMNZRADJMYv9HG4JZxmBkFgsA)

Answer (score 1):

## F#, <s>244</s> <s>241</s> 239 bytes

```fs
let rec g a=function|0->abs a|b->g b (a%b)
let h a b=g a b|>fun x->a/x,b/x
let s,n,d=List.fold2(fun(s,n,d)N D->
 let(N,D),(n,d)=h N D,h(n*D+N*d)(d*D)
 s@[sprintf"%i/%i"N D],n,d)([],0,1)nom div
printf"%s=%i/%i"(System.String.Join("+",s))n d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/fs-mono#NY9Na4QwFEX3/oqHILw4UWdsKRSJdOGqFDezFBdm4kfAiWWSFgv@d/tiKQ/e4tzDhTv3DsxyBwHNpciLJ7qXNpiJKv3taV68EsuL53b39NHfYIRODF/m5vRitnNSdtJCt8mkHEECdpFkR8EEHUgx@r@V5MNKarZyma1HbrnhSnxo69JhmVWO5OABWQ1VUgZAFta8Yhw9FBMQ5xOauDrVsWKo4ooFYN8a@/nQxg1hpLNIh2S1Rw02LT/zC/MDaU7wb1nxJ@L1x7r@nl4dBWP6vmiD4SnkljEDat9/AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP>=7.1, 190 Bytes

```php
<?function f($x,$y){for($t=1+$x;$y%--$t||$x%$t;);return$x/$t."/".$y/$t;}[$n,$d]=$_GET;for($p=array_product($d);$x=$n[+$k];$e+=$x*$p/$y)$r[]=f($x,$y=$d[+$k++]);echo join("+",$r)."=".f($e,$p);
```

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/40a0804afd3f3ba2fbfe1d6805f520a3b7920b39)

+14 Bytes for replacement `return$x/$t."/".$y/$t;` with `return$y/$t>1?$x/$t."/".$y/$t:$x/$t;` to output `n` instead of `n/1`

Answer (score 1):

## [setlX](https://randoom.org/Software/SetlX), 62 bytes

```
[a,b]|->join([x/y:[x,y]in a><b],"+")+"="++/[x/y:[x,y]in a><b];
```

#### ungolfed:

```
[a,b]|->                  define a function with parameters a and b
  join(                 
    [ x/y :               using set comprehension, make a list of fractions 
      [x,y] in a><b       from the lists zipped together
    ],
    "+"
  )                       join them with "+"
  + "="                   concat with an equals sign
  +                       concat with
  +/[x/y:[x,y]in a><b]    the sum of the list
;
```

[image: interpreter session]

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/) (Lambdabot), <s>94</s> <s>91</s> 86 bytes

```hs
t=tail.((\[n,_,d]->'+':n++'/':d).words.show=<<)
a#b|f<-zipWith(%)a b=t f++'=':t[sum f]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY6xasMwEIZ3P8VBKJbwWcVKCK2xuqRrli4dXBOU2saitmSkC6Gl7@6qNG2H3L8c3/8d3KDDWzeOi5lm5wl2zpJ3o9g7q9vkAh81afGkybiFFGkzCsZeaosHbJv8Ic3S0mZZepuWLRdn59sgwuDOqqp4olfHz77KP8z8bGhgN1zDURH00VdpSXU4TdA3C3WBdjp0AVQCUAOrC5S4jtk2GIHE@7hL3DQ89hh7@c1/p/7nBf5EXu42eIfFFtfyysiLqFwZTZJM2lhQMOl5fwA2e2NJnOzryft3YCvO4e/b5Qs)

Thanks @Laikoni for `-8` bytes!

#### Ungolfed

```hs
-- convert each fraction to a string (has format "n%d", replace '%' with '/' and prepend '+' ("+n/d"), keep the tail (dropping the leading '+')
t = tail.((\[n,_,d]->'+':n++'/':d).words.show=<<)
-- build a list of fractions
a # b = let f = zipWith(%) a b in
-- stringify that list, append "=" and the stringified sum of these fractions
  t f ++ "=" ++ t [sum f]
```

Comment: Your missing a `import Data.Ratio` for `%` which is not in Prelude.

Comment: You can save some bytes by replacing `"?"++` with `'?':`.

Comment: Whoops, totally missed that.. Thanks! Yup, fixed.

Comment: The shortening also works for `"/"++d` and `"="++`.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed.. But only for `"="++` :S

Comment: Rearranging saves some more bytes: `tail(f>>=t)++'=':(tail.t.sum)f`

Comment: Putting `tail` and `=<<` into `t` saves some more: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY6xasMwEIZ3P8VBKJbwWcVKCK2xuqRrli4dXBOU2saitmSkC6Gl7@6qNG2H3L8c3/8d3KDDWzeOi5lm5wl2zpJ3o9g7q9vkAh81afGkybiFFGkzCsZeaosHbJv8Ic3S0mZZepuWLRdn59sgwuDOqqp4olfHz77KP8z8bGhgN1zDURH00VdpSXU4TdA3C3WBdjp0AVQCUAOrC5S4jtk2GIHE@7hL3DQ89hh7@c1/p/7nBf5EXu42eIfFFtfyysiLqFwZTZJM2lhQMOl5fwA2e2NJnOzryft3YCvO4e/b5Qs "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: Neat, I like how you did `[sum f]` to pull out the `tail`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

## Google Sheets, <s>83</s> 81 bytes

```
=ArrayFormula(JOIN("+",TRIM(TEXT(A:A/B:B,"?/???")))&"="&TEXT(sum(A:A/B:B),"?/???"
```

<sub><sup>Saved 2 bytes thanks to Taylor Scott</sup></sub>

Sheets will automatically add 2 closing parentheses to the end of the formula.

The two arrays are input as the *entirety* of columns `A` and `B`. Empty rows below the inputs will throws errors.

Comment: you should be able to drop 2 bytes by dropping the terminal `))`

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 6, <s>72 bytes</s> 65 bytes

Native and automatic rationals *should* make this easy, but default stringification is still as decimal, so we have to `.nude` (*nu*merator and *de*nominator) which kills our score and makes the 1 ugly :(

```
my \n = 1,2,3,3,6; my \d = 2,9,3,2,4;
(n Z/d)».nude».join("/").join("+")~"="~([+] n Z/d).nude.join("/")
```

Update: Removed unneeded brackets, kill more space and use smarter map. Saves characters over Brad's solution at the cost of no not being a lambda sub.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Nice first answer!

Answer (score 0):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 32 bytes

```
/YQv'%i/%i+'wYD3L)61yUYQVwV47b&h
```

Try at [MATL online!](https://matl.io/?code=%2FYQv%27%25i%2F%25i%2B%27wYD3L%2961yUYQVwV47b%26h&inputs=%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+3%2C+6%5D%0A%5B2%2C+9%2C+3%2C+2%2C+4%5D&version=19.11.0)

#### Explanation

Consider `[1, 2, 3, 3, 6]`, `[2, 9, 3, 2, 4]` as input.

```
/         % Implicit inout. Divide element-wise
          % STACK: [0.5 0.222 1 1.5 1.5]
YQ        % Rational approximation (with default tolerance)
          % STACK: [1 2 1 3 3], [2 9 1 2 2]
v         % Conctenate all stack elements vertically
          % STACK: [1 2; 2 9; 1 2; 3 2; 3 2]
'%i/%i+'  % Push this string (sprintf format specifier)
          % STACK: [1 2; 2 9; 1 2; 3 2; 3 2], '%i/%i+'
wYD       % Swap, sprintf
          % STACK: '1/2+2/9+1/1+3/2+3/2+'
3L)       % Remove last entry
          % STACK: '1/2+2/9+1/1+3/2+3/2'
61        % Push 61 (ASCII for '=')
          % STACK: '1/2+2/9+1/1+3/2+3/2', 61
y         % Duplicate from below
          % STACK: '1/2+2/9+1/1+3/2+3/2', 61, '1/2+2/9+1/1+3/2+3/2'
U         % Evaluste string into a number
          % STACK: '1/2+2/9+1/1+3/2+3/2', 61, 4.722
YQ        % Rational approximation 
          % STACK: '1/2+2/9+1/1+3/2+3/2', 61, 85, 18
VwV       % Convert to string, swap, convert to string
          % STACK: '1/2+2/9+1/1+3/2+3/2', 61, '18', '85'
47        % Push 47 (ASCII for '/')
          % STACK: '1/2+2/9+1/1+3/2+3/2', 61, '18', '85', 47
b         % Bubble up in stack
          % STACK: '1/2+2/9+1/1+3/2+3/2', 61, '85', 47, '18'
&h        % Concatenate all stack elements horizontally. Implicitly display
          % STACK: '1/2+2/9+1/1+3/2+3/2=85/18'
```

Answer (score 0):

## R, 109 bytes

```
f=MASS::fractions;a=attributes
g=function(n,d)paste(paste(a(f(n/d))$f,collapse='+'),a(f(sum(n/d)))$f,sep='=')
```

requires the `MASS` library (for its `fractions` class). the function `g` returns the required output as a string.

[Try it online!](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=9f63cHQN) (R-fiddle link)

Answer (score 0):

## TI-BASIC, 100 bytes

```
:L₁⁄L₂                                              //Creates a fraction from Lists 1 & 2, 7 bytes
:toString(Ans→Str1                                  //Create string from list, 7 bytes
:inString(Ans,",→A                                  //Look for commas, 9 bytes
:While A                                            //Begin while loop, 3 bytes
:Str1                                               //Store Str1 to Ans, 3 bytes
:sub(Ans,1,A-1)+"+"+sub(Ans,A+1,length(Ans)-A→Str1  //Replace "," with "+", 33 bytes
:inString(Ans,",→A                                  //Check for more commas, 9 bytes
:End                                                //End while loop, 2 bytes
:Str1                                               //Store Str1 to Ans, 3 bytes
:sub(Ans,2,length(Ans)-2                            //Remove opening and closing brackets, 13 bytes
:Ans+"="+toString(expr(Ans                          //Add "=" and answer, 11 bytes
```

Note the `⁄` at the beginning, different from `/`. This makes the fractions hold their forms. It **does** work with negative fractions.

*Sigh*. TI-BASIC is *horrible* with strings. If all we had to do was print the fractions, and then their sum, the code would be:

#### TI-BASIC, 12 bytes

```
:L₁⁄L₂    //Create fractions from lists, 7 bytes
:Disp Ans //Display the above fractions, 3 bytes
:sum(Ans  //Display the answer, 2 bytes
```

That means that **88 bytes** of my code is spent just formatting the answer! *Hmph*.

Answer (score 0):

## C, 171 bytes

[**Try Online**](http://ideone.com/JPdAZC)

```c
i;t;x;y;f(int s,int*a,int*b){x=*a;y=*b;while(++i<s)x=(y-b[i])?(x*b[i])+(a[i]*y):(x+a[i]),y=(y-b[i])?(b[i]*y):y;for(i=1;i<=(x<y?x:y);++i)t=(x%i==0&&y%i==00)?i:t;x/=t;y/=t;}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Axiom, 212 bytes

```
C==>concat;S==>String;g(a)==C[numerator(a)::S,"/",denom(a)::S];h(a:List PI,b:List PI):S==(r:="";s:=0/1;#a~=#b or #a=0=>"-1";for i in 1..#a repeat(v:=a.i/b.i;s:=s+v;r:=C[r,g(v),if i=#a then C("=",g(s))else"+"]);r)
```

test

```
(5) -> h([1,3,4,4,5,6], [2,9,5,5,6,7])
   (5)  "1/2+1/3+4/5+4/5+5/6+6/7=433/105"
                                                             Type: String
(6) -> h([1,3,4,4], [2,9,5,5,6,7])
   (6)  "-1"
                                                             Type: String
```

Answer (score 0):

## Casio Basic, 161 Bytes

```
Dim(List 1)->A
for 1->I to A step 1
3*I-2->B
List 1[I]->C
List 2[I]->D
locate 1,B,C
locate 1,B+1,"/"
locate 1,B+2,D
C/D+E->E
next
locate 1,B+3,"="
locate 1,B+4,E
```

Explanation:

- Number of input is saved in `A`
- `A` iterations
- `B` acts as a counter for correct displaying
- `I`'th item of List 1 and 2 saved in `C` and `D`
- Displaying of Variable `C` / Variable `D`
- save `C`/`D`+`E` in `E`
- After last number locate `=` and `E`

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `Ṫ`, 12 bytes

```
/₌≬vS\+j∑\=$
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyLhuaoiLCIiLCIv4oKM4omsdlNcXCtq4oiRXFw9JCIsIiIsIlsyLCA5LCAzLCAyLCA0XVxuWzEsIDIsIDMsIDMsIDZdIl0=)

10 bytes of this is just getting the formatting right... /:

### Explained

```
/₌≬vS\+j∑\=$
/           # divide the lists, vectorising
 ₌≬vS\+j     # join each fraction on "+" (there's a bug where they get converted to decimal without vS :/)
       ∑    # get the sum of the fractions. 
        \=$ # place a "=" between the two
            # the Ṫ flag prints the entire stack without spaces. If it wasn't for the aforementioned joining bug, the last $ could be a j and the flag wouldn't be needed.
```