# Find the tangent of the sum of inverse tangents

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence

## Background

It can be shown that for any integer `k >= 0`, `f(k) = tan(atan(0) + atan(1) + atan(2) + ... + atan(k))` is a rational number.

## Goal

Write a complete program or function which when given `k >= 0`, outputs `f(k)` as a single reduced fraction (the numerator and denominator are coprime).

## Test cases

The first few values are

```
f(0) = (0,1)
f(1) = (1,1)
f(2) = (-3,1)
f(3) = (0,1)
f(4) = (4,1)
f(5) = (-9,19)
f(6) = (105,73)
```

## Rules

- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- [Input and output](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) may be in any
  convenient format. You may output `f(k)` as a string `numerator/denominator`, as a tuple of two integers, a fraction or rational object, etc. If you output a string, give two integers only, that is, output `3/2` instead of `1 1/2`.
- This is code-golf, the shortest answer (in bytes)
  wins.

Comment: Can you further specify in your test cases what the input/output values are?

Comment: Can we output as a rational number instead?

Comment: Also it would be helpful to specify precisely which input corresponds to each output.

Comment: Are the integers in the range in degrees or radians?

Comment: OEIS: [A180657](https://oeis.org/A180657)

Comment: The `atan(0)` term is unnecessary.

Comment: @Adám If the `atan(0)` wasn't there, then `f(0)` wouldn't be defined; but for `f(n); n > 0`, yes, it doesn't change the answer.

Comment: @pizzapants184 f(0) = tan∑∅ = tan 0 = 0

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Neither. They are in unit circle units.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer: If you use `tan` and `atan` on same angle units, that is a non-problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [M](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/m), 11 bytes

```
×C÷@+
R0;ç/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/3///B058PbHbS5ggysDy/X////vxkA)

Uses the OEIS formula `x(n) = (x(n-1)+n)/(1-n*x(n-1))` with `x(0) = 0`.

Answer (score 11):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <del>76</del> 72 bytes

```
from fractions import*
f=lambda k:Fraction(k and(k+f(k-1))/(1-k*f(k-1)))
```

Use the identity:

```
tan(A + B) = (tan(A) + tan(B)) / (1 - tan(A) * tan(B))
```

We have:

```
f(k) = 0                                    if k = 0
     = (k + f(k - 1)) / (1 - k * f(k - 1))  if k > 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LckxDsIwDADAnVd4q10aoTBWgpF/GIrBCrEjk4XXh6Xj6dqvv93OY0h4BQl@dHX7gtbm0eeDXD5c7xtDWW97YgG2DctRsKRMdMKcyryDhniAghoE2@uJOdPaQq2DLlO6Toug0vgD)

Thanks to Luis Mendo, save 4 bytes.

Comment: Hope you do not mind: I added a TiO link.

Comment: @LuisMendo LGTM, Edited.

Answer (score 11):

## Mathematica, 28 bytes

```
Fold[+##/(1-##)&,0,Range@#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fpmCr8N8tPyclWltZWV/DUFdZWVNNx0AnKDEvPdVBOVbtv0t@dEBRZl5JdJ6OgpKCrp2Cko5CWnRebKyOQjVQyEBHwdCgNvY/AA)

A longer, but more interesting approach (32 bytes):

```
Im@#/Re@#&@Product[1+n I,{n,#}]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fpmCr8N8z10FZPyjVQVnNIaAoP6U0uSTaUDtPwVOnOk9HuTZW7b9LfnRAUWZeSXSejoKSgq6dgpKOQlp0XmysjgJQiYKBjoKhQW3sfwA)

Comment: +1 `o'_'o` Mathematica and its built-ins `o'_'o`

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Not really in this case. OP is using series summation cleverly (if I read the code right).

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 14 bytes

Requires `⎕FR←1287` (**128** bit **F**loating-point **R**epresentation) for small input. Takes `k` as right argument.

```apl
1(∧÷,)3○¯3+.○⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qW9CjtgmGRhbm/9NADI1HHcsPb9fRNH40vfvQemNtPSD9qHfz//9ph1YYKBgqGCkYK5gomCqYAQA)

`⍳` integers one through `k` (zero is not needed as 0 = arctan 0)

`¯3+.○` sum of arcus tangents

`3○` tangent

`1(`…`)` apply the following tacit function with 1 as left argument and the above as right argument:

`∧` the lowest common multiple (of 1 and the right argument); gives the numerator

`÷` divided by

`,` the concatenation (of 1 and the right argument); gives the numerator and the denominator

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 52 bytes

This uses the OEIS series expansion:

```hs
import Data.Ratio
f 0=0%1
f n|p<-f$n-1=(p+n)/(1-n*p)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcUxDsMgDADAva@wokSCIpIwdIOpfUF@YKmQoibGIh77d8pwug9e33gcreWTSxV4oeC8oeRyS7CGdXJ9@rG3aSTrgmJDelHO0p11OzETBOCaSWCG1NWI754yZpjcoCF4D3uUZyGJJFd7/AE)

Or a pointfree version:

```hs
(scanl1(\f n->(f+n)/(1-n*f))[0%1..]!!)
```

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 80 bytes

```
f=n=>n?([a,b]=f(n-1),g=(a,b)=>a?g(b%a,a):b,c=g(d=b*n+a,e=b-n*a),[d/c,e/c]):[0,1]
```

Returns a [numerator, denominator] pair. Explanation: Let `f(n-1) = a/b` then `f(n) = atan(tan(n)+tan(a/b)) = (n+a/b)/(1-n*a/b) = (b*n+a)/(b-n*a)`. It then remains to reduce the fraction to its lowest terms.

[Online ES6 Environment](https://es6console.com/j63jz0l7/)

Answer (score 1):

## Casio-Basic, 35 bytes

```
tExpand(tan(sum(seq(tan⁻¹(n),n,0,k
```

tan<sup>-1</sup> should be entered as the one on the Trig keyboard; or the <sup>-1</sup> can be entered separately from the abc>Math keyboard. According to the fx-CP400's manual, it's a single two-byte character (764).

Function, 34 bytes for the code, +1 byte to add `k` as an argument.

**Explanation**

`seq(tan-1(n),n,0,k)` generates all the values for `tan-1(n)` from 0 to k.

`sum` adds them all together, then `tan` does the tangent function on them.

`tExpand` will then turn them into a single fraction.

Comment: @Adám This is Casio, not TI, so it's not done the same way.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casio_calculator_character_sets#Character_set_0xE5), `⁻` and `¹` are two bytes each; `E5CC` and `E5C1`.

Comment: @Adám oh nice, I didn't realise that article existed! However, this is an fx-CP400, not the 9860G; I just checked the manual, and the superscript -1 is actually a single character, code 764; so it's a single two byte character.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 36 bytes

```
n->imag(x=prod(i=0,n,1+i*I))/real(x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYoxDoAgDAC/0ji1ChEeALvPIFFIEy1N4@DvkeFuuJwWY990VEgwxGd@SsMvqfUTOQUnLm68HkS7XeXGj0bthjLv4CBO1FjeGRbweaqiENH4AQ)

Or the same length:

```
n->fold((x,y)->(x+y)/(1-x*y),[0..n])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYoxCoAwDAC/EpwSbWp9gP2IOAhSKUhaikP7@pjhbjiuXi3zUzXBDiocU3lvxO4GccS@DFpx4z4PckfwXk7SVBqK3cHBZtSW5bMwAUdTQiEi/QE)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>33</s> 26 bytes

```
0X)Iƒ©`N*+®`sN*-‚D¿D_i\¤}/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASwA0/8wNWFiMWX//zBYKUnGksKpYE4qK8KuYHNOKi3igJpEwr9EX2lcwqR9L///Ng)

**Explanation**

```
0X)                          # initialize stack with [0,1]
   Iƒ                        # for N in range [0 ... input] do:
     ©                       # store a copy of the current pair in the register
      `                      # push the pair separately to the stack
       N*                    # multiply the denominator with N
         +                   # add the numerator
          ®`s                # push the denominator then the numerator to the stack
             N*              # multiply the numerator by N
               -             # subtract it from the denominator
                D¿D          # get 2 copies of the greatest common divisor
                   0Qi  }    # if the gcd equals 0
                      \¤     # replace it with the denominator
                         /   # divide the pair with this number
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 30 bytes

```matlab
format rat
tan(sum(atan(0:k)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9ta2bN9T8tvyg3sUShKLGEqyQxT6O4NFcjEcQwsMrW1NT8/x8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 130 bytes

```forth
: g dup if tuck mod recurse then ;
: f 0 1 rot for 2dup i * + -rot swap i * - next
2dup g + abs over 0< 2* 1+ * >r i / swap r> / ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7LDoIwEEX3/YoTlhAeZQnGf0FowaiUtEX9exzA1dzHuclY5@OUj3Y/29YwMqwLd0tc@wcvN@BNv/pgiJOZaVWDpULjXURW1AdPSka@Z@HTnT5nNt@ojn6UtrsF3Nt4qgt1is6EuXpBy3Pjr6JaeSGaEBVoXTA4EQhTUCQ0JH9rz6AkEdF7SZ/OLao9ttsP)

Uses [my own implementation of gcd](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/194241/78410), and the OEIS formula. Takes `k` from the stack and returns two integers `denom num` on the stack. It took a lot of effort (and bytes) to normalize the fraction.

```forth
: g ( x y -- gcd 0 )
  dup if tuck mod recurse then
;

: f ( k -- denom num )
  0 1               \ push initial fraction with num=0, denom=1
  rot for           \ ( num denom ) loop from k to 0 inclusive
    2dup i * + -rot \ ( denom*k+num num denom )
    swap i * -      \ ( denom*k+num denom-num*k )
  next
  2dup g + abs      \ ( num denom gcd ) evaluate positive gcd and remove 0
  over 0< 2* 1+ *   \ ( num denom gcd' ) negate gcd if denom < 0
  >r i / swap r> /  \ ( denom/gcd' num/gcd' )
;
```

Answer (score 0):

### Julia 0.6.0 40 bytes

`k->rationalize(tan(sum(x->atan(x),1:k)))`

It's a straightforward implementation of the question. The precision of rationalize can sometimes be weird but works fine 99% of the time.