# Make me a square!

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

## Task

Given one non-whitespace printable character, make a 3x3 square representation of that input. For example, if the input is `#`, then the output is:

```
###
# #
###
```

## Rules

- The output format is strict, although a trailing newline is allowed. It means that the space in the middle is required, and also that the two newline characters separating the three lines are required.

## Testcases

Input: `#`

Output:

```
###
# #
###
```

Input: `A`

Output:

```
AAA
A A
AAA
```

Input: `0`

Output:

```
000
0 0
000
```

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest answer in bytes wins.

### Leaderboard

Here is a Stack Snippet to generate both a regular leaderboard and an overview of winners by language.

```js
/* Configuration */

var QUESTION_ID = 120052; // Obtain this from the url
// It will be like https://XYZ.stackexchange.com/questions/QUESTION_ID/... on any question page
var ANSWER_FILTER = "!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe";
var COMMENT_FILTER = "!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk";
var OVERRIDE_USER = 48934; // This should be the user ID of the challenge author.

/* App */

var answers = [], answers_hash, answer_ids, answer_page = 1, more_answers = true, comment_page;

function answersUrl(index) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" +  QUESTION_ID + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER;
}

function commentUrl(index, answers) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/" + answers.join(';') + "/comments?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + COMMENT_FILTER;
}

function getAnswers() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: answersUrl(answer_page++),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      answers.push.apply(answers, data.items);
      answers_hash = [];
      answer_ids = [];
      data.items.forEach(function(a) {
        a.comments = [];
        var id = +a.share_link.match(/\d+/);
        answer_ids.push(id);
        answers_hash[id] = a;
      });
      if (!data.has_more) more_answers = false;
      comment_page = 1;
      getComments();
    }
  });
}

function getComments() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: commentUrl(comment_page++, answer_ids),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      data.items.forEach(function(c) {
        if (c.owner.user_id === OVERRIDE_USER)
          answers_hash[c.post_id].comments.push(c);
      });
      if (data.has_more) getComments();
      else if (more_answers) getAnswers();
      else process();
    }
  });  
}

getAnswers();

var SCORE_REG = /<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/;

var OVERRIDE_REG = /^Override\s*header:\s*/i;

function getAuthorName(a) {
  return a.owner.display_name;
}

function process() {
  var valid = [];
  
  answers.forEach(function(a) {
    var body = a.body;
    a.comments.forEach(function(c) {
      if(OVERRIDE_REG.test(c.body))
        body = '<h1>' + c.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG, '') + '</h1>';
    });
    
    var match = body.match(SCORE_REG);
    if (match)
      valid.push({
        user: getAuthorName(a),
        size: +match[2],
        language: match[1],
        link: a.share_link,
      });
    
  });
  
  valid.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aB = a.size,
        bB = b.size;
    return aB - bB
  });

  var languages = {};
  var place = 1;
  var lastSize = null;
  var lastPlace = 1;
  valid.forEach(function (a) {
    if (a.size != lastSize)
      lastPlace = place;
    lastSize = a.size;
    ++place;
    
    var answer = jQuery("#answer-template").html();
    answer = answer.replace("{{PLACE}}", lastPlace + ".")
                   .replace("{{NAME}}", a.user)
                   .replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", a.language)
                   .replace("{{SIZE}}", a.size)
                   .replace("{{LINK}}", a.link);
    answer = jQuery(answer);
    jQuery("#answers").append(answer);

    var lang = a.language;
    if (/<a/.test(lang)) lang = jQuery(lang).text();
    
    languages[lang] = languages[lang] || {lang: a.language, user: a.user, size: a.size, link: a.link};
  });

  var langs = [];
  for (var lang in languages)
    if (languages.hasOwnProperty(lang))
      langs.push(languages[lang]);

  langs.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.lang > b.lang) return 1;
    if (a.lang < b.lang) return -1;
    return 0;
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; ++i)
  {
    var language = jQuery("#language-template").html();
    var lang = langs[i];
    language = language.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", lang.lang)
                       .replace("{{NAME}}", lang.user)
                       .replace("{{SIZE}}", lang.size)
                       .replace("{{LINK}}", lang.link);
    language = jQuery(language);
    jQuery("#languages").append(language);
  }

}
```

```css
body { text-align: left !important}

#answer-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

#language-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

table thead {
  font-weight: bold;
}

table td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b">
<div id="answer-list">
  <h2>Leaderboard</h2>
  <table class="answer-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="answers">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="language-list">
  <h2>Winners by Language</h2>
  <table class="language-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="languages">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="answer-template">
    <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="language-template">
    <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The fact that the size is fixed allows for some optimization. Answers form the linked challenge will probably not be competitive here. So I don't think it's a duplicate

Comment: I was the one who downvoted, for it for being a simple, boring challenge. I'm normally a fan of easy challenges, as they're a good place for new golfers to start but this just feels too easy.

Comment: @Shaggy it's a bad practise to downvote challenges just because you dont like them, please delete your downvote. For you finding it easy, it is about having as little as possible bytes and i don't think that is really easy.

Comment: @Ayoungcoder It is a perfectly valid reason to downvote a challenge.

Comment: @Shaggy: In terms of difficulty, there's difficulty to write the program, and difficulty to golf the program. This program is easy to write, but I'm not so sure it's easy to golf it.

Comment: In my opinion, this is a good challenge for people who are just getting started with code golfing. It's good to have a mix of difficulties. Overloading on any one type will be to the detriment of some part of the community. So, I'm glad this challenge was written.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>5</s> 3 bytes

```
Ｂ³Ｓ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/charcoal#@/9@z6JDm9/v2fz/vzIA) Edit: Saved 40% thanks to @carusocomputing. Explanation:

```
Ｂ   Draw a box
³   3×3 (second dimension is implicit if omitted)
Ｓ   Using the input character
```

Comment: I feel like this is cheating...>_>

Comment: Then, of course, `Ｂ³Ｓ` to cheat the living crap outta this.

Comment: Why would this be cheating? @carusocomputing and neil his anwser seems right to me

Comment: @Ayoungcoder "cheating" as in "seems cheap" not as in "literal cheating"; the code has a built-in for "print a box of dimensions n using character s", the shortest code for this challenge being: 1. Read input. 2. Define dimension. 3. Print box. The answer to this challenge logically won't be below 2 bytes if input is implicit.

Comment: @carusocomputing sorry, didnt know :), should it count this as caros' answer or Neil's answer :)

Comment: @carusocomputing Ah, the irony - the implicit square behaviour annoyed me in my answer to [Visualize the Euclidean algorithm again](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/119714/visualize-the-euclidean-algorithm-again).

Comment: @Ayoungcoder it's his answer :P. Crediting the -2 bytes I saved is the standard, nobody *takes* someone else's answer over by improving it.

Comment: @Ayoungcoder Although this is probably the shortest possible answer, I wouldn't accept it too soon to avoid putting prospective answerers off

Comment: @BetaDecay im keeping it like this to thanks neil and caros, i will give it to someone else when they have a shorter one.

Comment: inputting longer strings like abcdefgh also gives a fun output

Comment: Damnit! I swore I'd remember to try Charcoal at the next opportunity after seeing [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/116144/58974) - guess I forgot to remember!

Comment: @BetaDecay unless there exists a language that implicitly combines two of the 3 steps I previously mentioned, it's not possible to get a shorter answer; I don't know of any languages with "print 3x3 box of" or "3x3 shape using character x" and "in the shape of a box". Though, I agree, it is still possible to tie.

Comment: I wonder if Charcoal would benefit from a stack based approach. If it's too different, maybe I could add dialects (`Charstick` (?) for stack-based memory, and `Charbequeue` for queue-based memory maybe)

Answer (score 50):

## [Carrot](https://github.com/kritixilithos/Carrot/), 11 bytes

```
###
# #
###
```

[Try it online!](http://kritixilithos.github.io/Carrot/)

The program is in caret-mode, where `#`s are replaced with the input.

Comment: The feeling when a program which looks completely invalid at first is actually perfectly valid.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer ever heard of Perl?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer ever heard of Brainfuck?

Answer (score 19):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 32 bytes

```python
lambda s:s+s.join(s+'\n \n'+s)+s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqhQbFWsXayXlZ@Zp1GsrR6TpxCTp65drKld/L@gKDOvRCFNQ11ZXfM/AA)
For `s='a'` : the middle `s+'\n \n'+s` generates `a\n \na` and `s.join` turns it in `aa\na a\naa` (bold `a`s are the ones that `.join` adds), because `.join` accepts a string as an iterable, then it is surrounded with the two missing characters

Comment: How does this add the characters to the middle line? Could you explain the answer please?

Comment: @Notts90 added an explanation c:

Comment: thanks I didn't know .join could iterate a string.

Comment: This works in Python 3 too. Very cool BTW. (Also, using the same method `3*c+c.join('\n \n')+3*c` ties at 32.)

Answer (score 16):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 5 bytes

```
3Y6*c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@28caaaV/P@/uqM6AA)

#### Explanation

```
3Y6   % Push predefined literal: [true true true; true false true; true true true]
*     % Implicitly input a character. Multiply element-wise by its code point
c     % Convert to char. Implicitly display. Char 0 is displayed as space
```

Comment: that was quick! didnt expect a 5 byte to come that fast.

Comment: Code-golfing languages, you know... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Of course, because why wouldn't you have a predefined literal for [true true true; true false true; true true true]

Comment: @PunPun1000 That's actually used a lot (together with convolution) as it's the standard [8-connectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_connectivity) mask ([Moore neighboorhood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_neighborhood))

Comment: @LuisMendo That's awesome, learn something new on here every day, not always about code golfing

Answer (score 15):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
4×ð«û3ô»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#ARcA6P//MzBiw7tUScOwwqvigKEzw7TCu///WA)

```
INPUT    # ['R']                 | Implicit Input: 'R'
---------#-----------------------+-------------------------------
4×       # ['RRRR']              | Repeat string 4 times.     
  ð      # ['RRRR',' ']          | Push space onto top of stack.
   «     # ['RRRR ']             | Concatenate last 2 items.
    û    # ['RRRR RRRR']         | Palindromize.
     3ô  # [['RRR','R R','RRR']] | Split into 3 pieces.
       » # ['RRR\nR R\nRRR']     | Join with newlines
---------#-----------------------+-------------------------------
OUTPUT   # RRR                   | Implicitly print the top
         # R R                   | of the stack on exit.
         # RRR                   |
```

---

Original idea using 30 as a binary number (unfinished, someone else try this in another lang):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 12 bytes

```
30bûTIð«‡3ô»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#ARcA6P//MzBiw7tUScOwwqvigKEzw7TCu///WA)

Comment: [You have been outgolfed.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/123670/12537)

Answer (score 11):

## [Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3.6/), 33 bytes

```python
lambda c:f'{3*c}\n{c} {c}\n{3*c}'
```

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/HwJ4/2)

Comment: No problem. It looks like it's actually 3.6.1 being run; if you try `import sys` and then `sys.version` in the repl, it returns 3.6.1 rather than 3.5.2. No idea why it says 3.5.2 at the top then, seems like they have made a mistake there!

Comment: Oh, haha, a case of "don't always believe what you read" - thanks!

Answer (score 9):

### [RPL (Reverse Polish Lisp)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_Lisp), 60 characters

```
→STR 1 4 START DUP NEXT " " + SWAP + 4 ROLLD + + SWAP 2 PICK
```

(Note that "→" is a single character on the HP48 and compatible calculators)

Would visually represent what you want by having three items on the stack:

```
3.: "###"
2.: "# #"
1.: "###"
```

If you insist to return it as one string, one has to add the newline characters as well and combine the strings, left as exercise to the next tester.

[image: Input (can be anything, does not need to be a string)] [image: Entered code] [image: Result]

Explanation:

- `→STR`: Make the last object in the stack into a string. (So the input can be anything, e.g. a number.)
- `1` `4`: Push the number `1` and `4` to the stack.
- `START [...] NEXT`: Like a for loop but without access to the counter variable. Takes two numbers from the stack (here, we just have pushed `1` and `4`) and executes the code `[...]` the corresponding times (here, four times).
- `DUP`: Duplicate the last entry in the stack.
- `" "`: Push the string  (i.e. the string with one whitespace) to the stack.
- `+`: Take two objects from the stack and return them added together, for strings: Concatenated.
- `4`: Push the number `4` to the stack.
- `ROLLD`: Takes the last element (here: `4` that we just have pushed) from the stack and rolls the next element as far down the stack as the number we just took from the stack specifies.
- `SWAP`: Swaps the two last stack elements.
- `2`: Push `2` to the stack.
- `PICK`: Takes an element (here: The `2` we just pushed to the stack), interprets it as a number n, and copies the nth element from the stack.

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript, 28 bytes

```
c=>c+c+c+`
${c} ${c}
`+c+c+c
```

---

### Try it

```js
f=
c=>c+c+c+`
${c} ${c}
`+c+c+c
o.innerText=f(i.value="#")
i.oninput=_=>o.innerText=f(i.value)
```

```html
<input id=i maxlength=1><pre id=o>
```

Comment: I think you might be able to save a byte or two by storing the result of `c+'\n'+c` in a temporary.

Comment: Never mind, I miscounted, it's still 28 bytes.

Comment: @Neil: Yeah, there are a couple of options for assigning stuff to a variable,  but they all come in at 28 bytes or more.

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

1 byte thanks to Erik the Outgolfer.

```
x4,`Ks3Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@19hopPgXWwc@f//f3VldQA)

Comment: I was wondering how to do this... I had `x4µ©;⁶;®œs3Y` for 12 bytes because I couldn't figure out how to avoid having the repetition multiply my entire intermediate step but nice!

Comment: You know, there's a builtin `K` for doing `j⁶`. Oh, and there's a quick, `\``, to convert a dyad to a monad by using the same argument on both sides.

Answer (score 5):

## sed, <s>28</s> 18  bytes

```
s:.:&&&\n& &\n&&&:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/sed#@19spWelpqYWk6emACLU1Kz@/0/i@pdfUJKZn1f8X7cIAA)

Comment: this new one doesnt work, the old one did edit: it does but you forgot the : in the anwser

Comment: @Ayoungcoder Sorry, mis-pasted the final `:`. Fixed.

Comment: the try it online should be [Try it online!]: https://tio.run/nexus/sed#@19spWelpqYWk6emACLU1Kz@/0/i@pdfUJKZn1f8X7cIAA "sed – TIO Nexus"

Comment: @Ayoungcoder Of course, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), <s>76</s> 70 + 1 = 71 bytes

*Requires the `-c` flag*

```
(((((((({})))<((([])[]{}<>)<>)>)<(<>({})({}){}()()<>)>)<([]()()())>)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@68BBdW1mpqaNkBGdKxmdGx1rY2dJhABCQ0bO5AkCFfXamhqwISjY0EcDU0gR1Pz/3/V/7rJAA)

Comment: You can save 6 bytes if you replace `(()()()()()){}` with `([])[]{}`.

Comment: [Some competition](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120129/31716) :)

Answer (score 5):

## Java 7, <s>56</s> 55 bytes

-1 Thanks to  Leaky Nun for pointing out the space I missed

```java
String a(char s){return"...\n. .\n...".replace('.',s);}
```

Simply replaces the periods with the given character, for input #:

```java
...       ###
. .  =>   # #
...       ###
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#JYzBCsMgEETP8SuW9KBC2R/IN/SUY5vD1koqGCPuWigh355acpmBeTOT6zMGBy4SM9wopE11@cxYSJp91vCCpREzSglpvk9AZWYLrdmNXxa/4FoFc4NiyOiLtnZQ3a7Og@OcARn3pgJst@KlltQj4iMh/AWxx@JzJOeNRn1lO@zHfvwA)

Answer (score 5):

## PHP, 32 Bytes

```php
<?=strtr("000
0 0
000",0,$argn);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCjgUkksSs@zVVJWsuayt/tvY29bXFJUUqShZGBgwGWgAMQGBko6BjpgZZrW//8DAA)

Comment: Quite interestingly `<?=$a=$argn,"$a$a\n$a $a\n$a$a$a";` (real line break instead of \n of course) has exactly the same byte count.

Comment: @Christoph make it as your approach. i have not try this alternative way

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth, 7 bytes

```
jc3.[9d
```

[Try this online.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jc3.%5B9d&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%27%23%27%0A%27A%27%0A%270%27&debug=0)

Explanation:

```
jc3.[9d Expects quoted input.
  3     3
     9  9
      d ' '
        Q (eval'd input) as implicit argument
   .[   Pad B on both sides with C until its length is a multiple of A
 c      Split B to chunks of length A, last chunk may be shorter
j       Join A on newlines
```

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to carusocomputing.*

```
Ð¶¹ðJû
```

Explanation:

```
         # Implicit input                  # ['R']
 Ð       # Repeat string three times       # ['R', 'R', 'R']
  ¶      # Push newline character          # ['R', 'R', 'R', '\n']
   ¹     # Push first input                # ['R', 'R', 'R', '\n', 'R']
    ð    # Push space                      # ['R', 'R', 'R', '\n', 'R', ' ']
     J   # Join stack                      # ['RRR\nR ']
      û  # Palindromize ("abc" -> "abcba") # ['RRR\nR R\nRRR']
         # Implicit output                 # []
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f@PD0Q9sO7Ty8wevw7v//EwE)

Comment: Oooo... Smart, I never think about how palindromize works on newlines.

Comment: `Ð¶¹ðJû` for 6 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), <s>61</s>, 59 bytes

```
(((((((({})))<([][][]())>)<(([][][]()){})>)<([]()()())>)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@68BBdW1mpqaNhrRsSCooalpB@QgeEBZO7CshiYIAjmamv//q/zXTQYA)

This is 58 bytes of code `+1` byte for the `-c` flag which enables ASCII input and output.

Explanation:

```
(((
   (
    (
     (

      #Duplicate the input 3 times
      ((({})))

#Push 10 (newline)
<([][][]())>

     #Push the input again
     )

#Push 32 (space)
<(([][][]()){})>

    #Push the input again
    )

#Push 10 (newline)
<([]()()())>)

#Push input 3 times
)))
```

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>49</s> 47 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to 2501!*

```c
j;f(i){for(j=12;j;)putchar(--j%4?j-6?i:32:10);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#@59lnaaRqVmdll@kkWVraGSdZa1ZUFqSnJFYpKGrm6VqYp@la2afaWVsZGVooGld@z8zr0QhNzEzT0OzmktBQSFNQ91RXdMaynRCMJURTD0Qs/Y/AA) has a trailing newline

Comment: You can save two bytes by doing: `for(j=11;j;)...`

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 34 bytes

```python
lambda s:s*3+"\n"+s+" "+s+"\n"+s*3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqhQbFWsZaytFJOnpF2sraQAJsEcLeP/BUWZeSUaaRrqyuqamlwQHowGijoCRf8DAA)

Comment: -1 byte: `lambda x:x*3+'\n%s '%x+x+'\n'+x*3`

Answer (score 3):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 36 bytes

```matlab
x=repmat(input(0),3);x(5)=32;disp(x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@19hW5RakJtYopGZV1BaomGgqWOsaV2hYappa2xknZJZXKBRofn/v7qDOgA)

#### Explanation

This creates a 3x3 char matrix with the input char repeated, and sets its 5th entry in column-major order (i.e. its center) to `32` (ASCII for space).

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 5 bytes

```
dQA.X
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pyke#@58S6KgX8f9/IAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>27</s> 25 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to  Level River St

```ruby
->x{[s=x*3,x+" "+x,s]*$/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#S7T9r2tXUR1dbFuhZaxToa2koKRdoVMcq6WiX/u/KDUxJSczL7VYLzexoLqmuIZLoaC0pFghMbpYr7ikKLMglqv2vzKXI5cBFwA)

Comment: when you are doing anwsers like this, please also include the footer as code because it does not work without

Comment: @Ayoungcoder this is an anonymous function. you can assign it to a variable (`f=...`) then call it with `f.call(...)`

Comment: You can use a literal newline inside quotes instead of `"\n"` for a saving of 1 byte . Even better use `$/` which is a special variable set to newline by default - saving 2 bytes.

Comment: 1 byte less than the `tr` solution. nice work

Answer (score 3):

## Brainfuck, 40 bytes

```
+++++[->++<<++++++>],...>.<.<++.>.>.<...
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brainfuck#@68NAtG6dtraNjZgtrZdrI6enp6dno0eUABIg1h6ev//KwMA) *Requires an implementation that can access left of the starting position.*

Also see: [Graviton's brainfuck answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120124/66421) which takes a different approach (but is longer).

---

### Explanation:

Brainfuck can do a lot of cool tricks with its limited instruction set. Unfortunately, this answer doesn't use any of them, because it's cheaper (in terms of bytes) to just hardcode everything.

```
+++++[->++<<++++++>]                         Sets the cells to |5*6|>0<|5*2|
,                   Takes input character into the middle cell | 30|>#<| 10|
...                                Print the top of the square | 30|>#<| 10| ###
>.                                   Print a newline character | 30| # |>10|    \n
<.                               Print another input character | 30|>#<| 10| #
<++.                  Add 30+2 for a space character and print |>32| # | 10|  _
>.                   And just print the 5 remaining characters | 32|>#<| 10|   #
>.                                                             | 32| # |>10|    \n
<...                                                           | 32|>#<| 10| ###
```

# = input character, _ = space (ASCII 32), \n = newline (ASCII 10)

---

Results in this beautiful box (for input '+'):

```
+++
+ +
+++
```

Answer (score 3):

## Vim, 9 keystrokes

Assuming the input char is present in a buffer, vim makes this straightforward

```
x3pY2plr<space>
```

There is probably some magic vim commands of use here (there always seem to be some) so improvement suggestions are welcome. Only one keystroke behind V!

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is as short as it can get. Nice answer!

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 11 bytes

```
jc++K*z4dK3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PytZW9tbq8okxdv4/38A)

**Explanation:**

```
jc++K*z4dK3    expects a single char as input

j              joins on new line
 c        3    chops array into 3 sized pieces
  +            joins +K*z4d and K
   +           joins K*z4 and d
    K          initialize variable K as *z4
     *z4       duplicate the input 4 times
        d      variable initialized to string " "
         K     calls variable K, in this case *z4
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 3):

## AWK, <s>28</s> <s>26</s> 25 bytes

```
$0=$0$0$0RS$0FS$0RS$0$0$0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v9fxcBWxQAEg4JVDNyCITQI/v@vDAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [StupidStackLanguage](https://esolangs.org/wiki/StupidStackLanguage), 28 bytes

```
jfffavvflflqvvvviifblflflfff
```

[Try it online!](https://lebster.xyz/projects/stustala#5f741f9d65b18913fc56acfc)

### Explanation

```
j # Get the input (x)
fff # first 3
avv # new line
fl # print new line
fl # first x
qvvvviifb # space
lf # second x
lf # new line
lfff # last 3 x's
```

Comment: Welcome to the site :)

Answer (score 2):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>24</s> 23 bytes

```
i:o:o:oao:o84*o:a0!.<o$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/fish#@59plQ@CiUBsYaKVb5VooKhnk6/y/38gAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
r9*4St3/N*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v8hSyyS4xFjfT@v/f2UA)

Explanation:

```
r9*4St3/N* e# Expects single char (token) as input
r          e# Get input token (C)
 9*        e# Repeat C 9 times
   4St     e# Set the 5th char of C to be a space
      3/   e# Split into parts of length 3
        N* e# Join by newlines
```

Answer (score 2):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 8 bytes

```
x3p2Ùlr
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@19hXGB0eGZOkcL//8oA)

Comment: V has a (undocumented?) `<M-h>ollow` command that lets you hollow out the inside of your box:  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/v8K4wOjwzMMr/v9XBgA "V – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [J-uby](http://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), <s>22</s> 20 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to [@Jordan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/11261/jordan)

```rb
:tr&"...
. .
..."&?.
```

#### Explanation

`String#tr` is Ruby's character-wise replace method. The first `&` binds `:tr` to `"...\n. .\n..."`, and the second partially applies `'.'` to it. Effectively, this is `->s{"...\n. .\n...".tr('.',s)}`

Comment: Would `:tr` work as well as `:gsub` here?

Comment: @Jordan yes, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## C#,50 bytes

```
a=>Console.Write(a+a+a+"\n"+a+" "+a+"\n"+a+a+a);
```

Test Case:

```
var f = new Action<string>(
a=>Console.Write(a+a+a+"\n"+a+" "+a+"\n"+a+a+a);
);
f("#");
```

Comment: You need to fully qualify the `Console` i.e. `System.Console..`

Answer (score 2):

## Windows batch, 37 bytes

```
@echo %1%1%1
@echo %1 %1
@echo %1%1%1
```

Simply outputs the first command-line argument in a square form.

Answer (score 2):

## Z80 or 8080 Assembly, 21 bytes machine code

Assume a memory mapped I/O device:

```
              Z80                  8080
3A xx xx    ld  a, (input)      lda  input       ; get input character
11 0A 20    ld  de, 200ah       lxi  d, 200ah   ; space & newline
21 yy yy    ld  hl, output      lxi  h, output  ; get output address
77          ld  (hl), a         mov  m, a       ; output character * 3
77          ld  (hl), a         mov  m, a
77          ld  (hl), a         mov  m, a
73          ld  (hl), e         mov  m, e       ; output newline
77          ld  (hl), a         mov  m, a       ; output character
72          ld  (hl), d         mov  m, d       ; output space
77          ld  (hl), a         mov  m, a       ; output character
73          ld  (hl), e         mov  m, e       ; output newline
77          ld  (hl), a         mov  m, a       ; output character * 3
77          ld  (hl), a         mov  m, a
77          ld  (hl), a         mov  m, a
76          halt                hlt             ; or C9 ret
```

No interpreter needed!

Hexdump:

```
0000: 3A 00 FF 11 0A 20 21 01 FF 77 77 77 73 77 72 77
0010: 73 77 77 77 76
```

where the input address is at FF00h and the output address is mapped at FF01h. The actual addresses will depend on the actual hardware. Of course this assumes the I/O is memory mapped. If it is I/O mapped, it would take several extra bytes because Z80 & 8080 I/O instructions are two bytes each. This also assumes the output device interprets 0Ah as a newline and doesn't require a CR (0Dh) which would add an extra 4 bytes to the program.

Comment: Welcome to Codegolf.stackexchange, while it seems that you have everything under control please do read the help center and the list of faqs. Good first post

Comment: Can you provide a hexdump of your code?

Comment: The hex bytes are in the first column, but if you want a "pure" hexdump, I've added it.

Answer (score 2):

## Emacs, 15 keystrokes

The current buffer must only contain the input character, and the cursor must be at the start of the line.

```
C-k C-y C-y C-y C-a C-k C-y RET C-y C-b BACKSPACE SPC C-e RET C-y
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>7</s> 6 bytes using the [canvas](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175520/87488) and [compressed integers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175520/87488).

```
3IŽ9¦Λ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f2PPoXstDy87N/v9fGQA)

Comment: -1 byte by simply changing the `Ƶ‘0«` to `Ž9¦` (see the [_How to compress large integers?_ section of this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210)).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks, I was trying to use compressed integers but it wasn't getting the 0 at the start.

Comment: You're right, 0s at the start (both with compressed integers and compressed integer lists) doesn't work. But since it has to be a square anyway, and your previous answer was appending the `0` at the end, it can be a single compressed integer `2460` to save a byte. :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 31 bytes

```python
lambda s:3*s+f'\n{s} {s}\n'+3*s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHYylirWDtNPSavurhWAYhj8tS1gUL/C4oy80o00jQy8wpKSzQ0NTX/GwIA)

Answer (score 2):

## [MAWP](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), 29 bytes

```
|!;!;!;25W;!;84W;!;25W;!;!;;.
```

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/v1.1?code=%7C!%3B!%3B!%3B25W%3B!%3B84W%3B!%3B25W%3B!%3B!%3B%3B.&input=E)

-6 bytes from Dion's straightformard solution.

## [MAWP](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), 35 bytes

```
%|7[1A~!~]////25W//84W//25W////~[;]
```

Manually shifting the stack was more practical than trying to loop through it and make a box.

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/v1.1?code=%7C!%3B!%3B!%3B25W%3B!%3B84W%3B!%3B25W%3B!%3B!%3B%3B.&input=E)

Comment: Is this even golfed??

Comment: ...Ok, I take it back.

Comment: Doesn't something so straightforward like [this](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/v1.1?code=%7C!%3B!%3B!%3B25W%3B!%3B84W%3B!%3B25W%3B!%3B!%3B%3B.&input=E) work..?

Comment: What was I thinking when I made this?!

Answer (score 1):

## Swift3, 50 bytes

```
[1,2,3].map{$0==2 ? print(c+" "+c) : print(c+c+c)}
```

This uses the ternary operator to print different strings, depending on the row.

[Try it online](https://repl.it/Ht17/1)

Answer (score 1):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/L3viathan/Aceto), 19 bytes

```
nppk
pKLp
pppn
,kpp
```

Read a single character (`,`), then activate sticky mode (`k`). Print it three times, a newline and then the character again (`pppnp`).

Deactivate sticky mode (`K`), then load the empty string from quick storage (`L`), print it (`p`), activate sticky mode again (`k`), and print the rest (`pnppp`).

Answer (score 1):

### C#, <strike>74</strike> <strike>71</strike> 66 bytes

```
m=>{System.Console.WriteLine("{0}{0}{0}\n{0} {0}\n{0}{0}{0}",m);};
```

golfed 5 bytes thanks to an anon

Comment: You can save some bytes if you use `r==1?" ":m` directly in `WriteLine`, instead of assigning it to `s`.

Comment: You need to fully qualify the `Console`

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tio-transpilers), 48 bytes

Great simple challenge.

```
,...>++++++++++.<.>+[->+>+++<<]>>-.<<<.>>-.<<...
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brainfuck#@6@jp6dnpw0HejZAXrSunTZIzMYm1s5OV8/GBigIpoFq//9XBgA)

## Explanation

```
,...              : take input, print it 3 times
>++++++++++.      : print ASCII with index 10 (new line)
<.>               : print input.
+[->+>+++<<]>>-.  : add 1 to 10, triple it, subtract one and print it (space)
<<<.>>-.<<...     : print input, newline, and input 3 times
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 8 bytes

```
4Y"0yv3e
```

Unlike my other MATL answer, this builds the output manually, without using any predefined literal.

Try it at [MATL Online!](https://matl.iot/?code=4Y%220yv3e&inputs=%27%5E%27&version=19.10.0)

#### Explanation

Consider input `'^'` as an example.

```
      % Implicitly input one char.
4Y"   % Repeat 4 times. Gives a string.     STACK: '^^^^'
0     % Push 0. Char 0 is shown as space.   STACK: '^^^^', 0 
y     % Duplicate from below.               STACK: '^^^^', 0, '^^^^'
v     % Concatenate everything vertically.  STACK: ['^';'^';'^';'^';0'^';'^';'^';'^';'^']
3e    % Reshape into a 3-row char matrix.   STACK: ['^^^';'^ ^';'^^^']
      % Implicitly display.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 19 bytes

```
i:o:o:oao:$o" "|;o~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/fish#@59plQ@CiflWKvlKCko11vl1//9bAwA)

Answer (score 1):

### R, 44 bytes

```
cat(y<-rep(scan(,''),4),' ',y,sep='',fill=3)
```

Test and output:

```
> cat(y<-rep(scan(,''),4),' ',y,sep='',fill=3)
1: #
2: 
Read 1 item
###
# #
###
>
```

Comment: You can drop a few bytes by returning an anonymous function, but you can do even better by reading from stdin: 

`cat(y=rep(scan(,''),4),' ',y,sep='',fill=3)` is 43 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

### C#, 30 bytes

```c#
s=>s+s+s+$"\n{s} {s}\n"+s+s+s;
```

Compiles to a `Func<string, string>`.

Using `Replace` for 32 bytes.

```c#
c=>@"###
# #
###".Replace('#',c);
```

Compiles to a `Func<char, string>`.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Thanks, for some reason I have a problem typing `string` the right way round...

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 18 bytes

```
:`$
$_$_
*2=`.
```

Half of this code looks like trailing empty lines, I like that :)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@2@VoMKlEq8Sz6VlZJugx6XAxfX/vzIA)

#### Explanation

There are three stages in this program, each of them prints a line of the output, in sequence.

```
:`$
$_$_
```

Add two more copies of the input at the end and print the resulting string.

```
*2=`.
```

There's a single space in the second line. This stage replaces the second character of the string with a space, prints the result, and then reverts the string to what it was before (thanks to the `*`)

The two final empty lines are a replacement stage with no effect. This is only needed because a final stage with no printing modifier implicitly prints the resulting string.

Comment: Save 1 byte by removing the third stage and putting the second stage into a group. The implicit print then moves from the stage to the group, allowing the stage's own dry run to be an additional output. (The `(` needs to be at the start of the third line for this to work.)

Answer (score 1):

## R, <s>43</s> 40 bytes

`cat(gsub("y",scan(,""),"yyy\ny y\nyyy"))`

Saved 3 bytes thanks to Giuseppe.

Explanation: create a box using the character "y" and then substitute the input character.

Comment: You can drop 3 bytes by reading `x` from stdin instead of making it a function: `cat(gsub("y",scan(,""),"yyy\ny y\nyyy"))`

Comment: using `1` in place of `"y"` saves 2 more bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 27 bytes

```
/\\\#//\#\#\#
\#\ \#
\#\#\#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/slashes#@68fExOjrK8fowyCXEBCAUIB4f//AA)

Since there is no other way to take input in ///, it is hard-coded.

```
/\\\#/INPUT HERE/\#\#\#
\#\ \#
\#\#\#
```

Version that takes input in Itflabtijtslwi (28 bytes):

```
GG\\\#GG\#\#\#
\#\ \#
\#\#\#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl5#fY5bS8NAEIXf8yuyZKAzpXSJj25DsbQukSKIAR@ctkgT20B6oRMQifGvxzURhFpk4AzM5TsHVtFo1JvdT1dxcju/mSTxXfI4f4p7Zr09HE1jLTMHToPv8pz4XXPV/H3z3rZ5kWFIVf6KopbWIo6vn5eaefHBPKT@mKxVSqjavXsgEYTG6ae4AxyShlBvxEAabbJyjWQ6nGgH4QcQnrmTVFNV11khnQV29Fbtok9K@YeT7xYtsbU6nvJ9iRCS@X3T58HowuQnKIIMIKXIIQZwRZcTn03@TZ5VxYuUpq6b4As)

Answer (score 1):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), <s>23</s> 20 bytes

Brute-forcing this is shorter than fancy string-flips...

```
?;+A+A?A+@ `+A?A+A+A
```

---

Original answer:

```
A=;+A+A+@┘`+A?A+@ `+_fA
```

Explanation:

```
A=;     ; gets a cmd line parameter and assigns it to A$
        This overrides that value by
  +A+A    appending itself two times
  +@┘`    Then a literal newline
  +A      And another copy of the input char
?       PRINT
  A       The combined A$ ("###\n#")
  +@ `    a space
  +_fA    and then the flipped version of A$
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>11</s> 9 bytes

```
³+R+U+S ê
```

- Saved 2 bytes thanks to [obarakon](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61613/obarakon).

[Try it online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=sytSK1UrUyDq&input=IiMi)

---

### Explanation

```
    :Implicit input of string U
³   :Repeat input 3 times
+R  :Append newline
+U  :Append input
+S  :Append space
ê   :Duplicate string, excluding last character, reverse it and append it to original
```

---

### Alternative, 9 bytes

I can't decide which version I prefer.

```
[U³RUS]¬ê
```

[Try it online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=W1WzUlVTXazq&input=IiMi)

---

### Alternative, 10 bytes

I really liked this version, but sadly it came in at a byte too big.

```
NpU²RUS ¬ê
```

[Try it online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=TnBVslJVUyCs6g==&input=IiMi)

Comment: Nice! `p3 ` can be shortened to `³`

Comment: Aha, hadn't spotted that. Thanks again, @obarakon.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (ES6), 32 bytes

```
i=>`###
# #
###`.replace(/#/g,i)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 26 bytes

```
./v.o;@?/i:::Ns:Ss:Nu/:::s
```

This is the first piece of Cubix code I've ever written...I was originally going to try to answer the [Try to make a cube](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/121651/try-to-make-a-cube) challenge, but I figured I'd answer the original (easier) question first. Cubix is pretty cool!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cubix#@6@nX6aXb@1gr59pZWXlV2wVXGzlV6oPZBf//28MAA) and also [Watch the interpeter!](http://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=Li92Lm87QD8vaTo6Ok5zOlNzOk51Lzo6OnM=&input=Mw==&speed=20)

Answer (score 1):

## [Syms](https://github.com/CatsAreFluffy/syms), 21 bytes

```
{}<[[[++~[{& &}~[>~>>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K67MLf7/v7rWJjo6Wlu7LrpaTUGtti7ars7O7v9/EwA)

Comment: oops, didnt allow trailing [] but never specified it, lucky ig guess :)

Comment: Um why is `-i` on

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 23 + 1 (-p) = 24 bytes

The brute force way seems to be the shortest.

```perl
$_.="$_$_
$_ $_
$_$_$_"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lXs9WSSVeJZ5LJV4BTIKg0v//Wv/yC0oy8/OK/@v6muoZGBr81y0AAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 8 bytes

**Solution:**

```
3 3#5$4#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/31jBWNlUxURZyVHp/38A)

**Example:**

```
> 3 3#5$4#"@"
("@@@"
 "@ @"
 "@@@")
```

**Explanation:**

Evaluated right-to-left. Build `'AAAA'`, then `'AAAA '` and then shape into the 3x3 grid required.

```
3 3#5$4# / the solution
      4# / take 4 of whatever is to the right
    5$   / right pad with whitespace to length 5
3 3#     / shape into 3x3 grid
```

**Bonus:**

The solution is a polyglot for **q/kdb+**:

```
q)3 3#5$4#"*"
"***"
"* *"
"***"
```

Comment: cool way of doing it

Answer (score 1):

## [Pepe](//github.com/Soaku/Pepe), 54 bytes

```
REEeREEEeeReeerREeeeeEeEeReeereeeEeeeeeReeeREEeeReReee
```

[Try it](https://soaku.github.io/Pepe/#T-dH@!79HU8H!l.H)

**Explanation:**

```
REEe        # Input as str
REEEee      # Duplicate it
Reee        # Output whole stack
rREeeeeEeEe # Insert linefeed (10) to the stack
Reee        # Output whole stack
reeeEeeeee  # Print space (' ')
Reee        # Output whole stack
REEee       # Go to next position
ReReee      # Pop it (space) and output the whole stack
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/), 30 bytes

```
f(s)=>'$s$s$s\n$s $s\n$s$s$s';
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0ksKvn/P02jWNPWTl2lGARj8lSKFSAUCKpb/89NzMzT0KzmUlAoKMrMK9FI01BPVNfUtEYWSAIL1P4HAA)

Answer (score 1):

## *[Acc!!](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Acc!!)*, 58 bytes

```
N
Count i while 11-i {
Write _+i%4/3*(10-_)+i%6/5*(32-_)
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOTkr6/9@Pyzm/NK9EIVOhPCMzJ1XB0FA3U6GaK7wosyRVIV47U9VE31hLw9BAN14TyDHTN9XSMDYCcrhq//9XBgA)

#### How?

Let's lay out the desired output in a line, substituting `_` for the newlines, and look at patterns and indices.

```
###_# #_###
01234567890
```

We need newlines at indices 3 and 7, a space at index 5, and the input character at all other indices. To put it a different way, for index `i`, we want newline when `i%4 == 3`, space when `i%6 == 5`*, and the input character otherwise.

So, after reading the input character into the accumulator with `N`, we run a `Count` loop from 0 up to but not including 11. Iff `i%4` is 3, `i%4/3` is 1, and we output `_+(10-_)` i.e. 10 i.e. newline. Iff `i%6` is 5, `i%6/5` is 1, and we output `_+(32-_)` i.e. 32 i.e. space. Otherwise, we output `_` i.e. the accumulator value i.e. the input character. Fortunately, the two modulo cases are never true at the same time; this would happen at index 11, but we stop at index 10.

---

* The modulo operation would seem unnecessary here, but (as far as I can tell) it is the shortest way to test `i == 5` in *Acc!!*, which doesn't have a comparison operator.

Answer (score 1):

### [W](https://github.com/a-ee/w) `d` `n`, 8 bytes

```
º±▀σ\g┘╒
```

Uncompressed:

```
4*:' S++3,
```

Explanation:

```
4*         Repeat input 4 times
  :' S++   Put space in middle, append input * 4
        3, Chop into 3 equal pieces
Flag: n Join with newlines
```

### [W](https://github.com/A-ee/w) `d`, <del>13</del> <del>11</del> 9 bytes

Here's a version without chopping or similar built-ins.

```
↨i`♣T'@└µ
```

### Explanation

Uncompressed is:

```
' a++bab++E
```

```
          E % Foreach in the string:
' a++       % (implicit) input, the space, and input
     bab++  % Output the string created by the input,
            % the current item, and the input
            % With a newline
            % The None isn't outputted
```

Answer (score 1):

## Keg, 11 bytes

```
???
? ? 
???
```

It really just replaces the `?`s with the input!

Alterate 11 byter

```
¿3*:&
? ?
&
```

Comment: Neither program works on TIO

Comment: Because Keg needs a pull on TIO

Comment: @JoKing Dennis is not very active this week. He didn't get the latest interpreter on TIO yet.

Comment: @JoKing TIO is 19 commits behind the Keg repo

Answer (score 1):

## [naz](https://github.com/sporeball/naz), 46 bytes

```
1x1f0m9a1a1o0x1r2x1v3o1f1v1o0m4a8m1o1v1o1f1v3o
```

Strictly speaking, the above program outputs the exact byte stream required to make the square, though the top of the square will be misaligned given that the interpreter linked above always prepends `output:` to program output.

**Explanation** (with `0x` commands removed)

```
1x1f0m9a1a1o     # Function 1
                 # Reset the register, add 10 and output (produces a newline)
1r2x1v           # Read the first byte of input and store it in variable 1
3o               # Output the byte 3 times
1f               # Call function 1
1v1o0m4a8m1o1v1o # Output variable 1, output 32 (space), then output variable 1
1f               # Call function 1
1v3o             # Output variable 1 3 times
```

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](https://esolangs.org/wiki/GolfScript), 15 bytes

```
...n\." "\.n\..
```

**Explanation**

At the beginning of the program, the input is put onto the stack. Each `.` copies the top of stack. Each `n` pushes a newline onto the stack. `" "` pushes a space. `\` swaps the top two elements. At the end of the program, the stack is output to the standard output.

[Try it Online](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/X09PLy9GT0lBKQZE6/3/DwA)

Comment: [13 bytes](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/30RLT11BPUZb21g/T@v/f2UA)

Answer (score 1):

## TI-BASIC, 14 + 6 = 20 bytes

This submission uses two programs, the main one and a helper program called `prgmΘ`.

```
prgmΘ:Disp Ans+" "+Ans:prgmΘ         ;main program

Disp Ans+Ans+Ans                     ;helper program "prgmΘ"
```

Input is a string stored in Ans.

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 13 bytes

```
4*.' '\++3/n*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/30RLT11BPUZb21g/T@v/f2UA)

### Explanation

```
              # input #
4*            # ["####"]
  .           # ["####","####"]
   ' '        # ["####","####"," "]
      \       # ["####"," ","####"]
       ++     # ["#### ####"]
         3/   # [["###" "# #" "###"]]
           n* # [["###\n# #\n###"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

Husk is *way* easier to use than Pyth.

```
C3w½*8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/39m4/NBeLYv///8rKSoBAA)

## Explanation

```
    *8 Repeat the input 8 times. "!" -> "!!!!!!!!"
   ½   Halve the input. "!!!!!!!!" -> ["!!!!","!!!!"]
  w    Join with spaces. ["!!!!","!!!!"] -> "!!!! !!!!"
C3     Split into chunks of 3. ["!!!","! !","!!!"]

Husk automatically outputs lists joined with newlines
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup><s>12</s></sup> 9 bytes

```
3 3$4j1#]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/jRWMVUyyDJVj/2typSZn5CukKag7qkOY6upwIWX1/wA)

*-3 thanks to FrownyFrog*

Comment: `3 3$4j1#]` for 9

Comment: That is quite nice.  I had long forgotten about that complex trick, if I ever knew it.

Answer (score 1):

## [1+](https://esolangs.org/wiki/1%2B), <s>40</s> 38 bytes

```
,";";";(|11+""*")++";^";()**;";^;";";;
```

Longer than I thought. Ungolfed, but it's a start.

Answer (score 1):

## [Poetic](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/), 208 bytes

```
BOX,OR SQUARE
i was creating a side,i built a box
i looked,it was four-sided
i am somewhat weirdly earnest,however,about n*n squares having a"no-holes-in-a-drawing"shape
i am trying to produce regular squares
```

[Try it online!](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/tio/index.html?NY3BDoIwEETvfsUGb6b9CE08EzEmXhe60sbS1W0L8vVYMB5n5uXNqb6ruoHr5XZszjsHE0bohDC50ANCdIaUgzY7n0ps@VMYz/wko1za6Adn0StnyoQDRB5oslhGcmL8DIQSKCZleaKRRGHLOUE4BIjvjEIRLI7bXRVYW/YUtQsatRGcSl9Fiy/6yZPMK5kYXsImdwRCffYof9eyX1o0Xw)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 34 bytes

```
{`0:x,x,x,"\n",x," ",x,"\n",x,x,x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k#eJxLs6pOMLCq0AFBpZg8JRCloITgAGEtF1eakrISkHAEEQZKAHu9DRU=)

The straightforward (although long) answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2) `j`, 40 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 5 bytes

```
4*ð+∞²
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyLhuaBqPSIsIiIsIjQqw7Ar4oiewrIiLCIiLCI2Il0=)

Bitstring:

```
0100101010111010101000100000000000001010
```

optimal encoding for a 6 byter

Answer (score 0):

## Braingolf, <s>34</s> 20 bytes

```
...#
<.># <.>#
<..&@
```

Little disappointed that this isn't easily golfed.
At least it's shorter than JavaScript

#### Explanation:

For input `#`

```
                   | [35]
...                | [35,35,35,35]
   #<newline>      | [35,35,35,35,10]
<.>                | [35,35,35,35,10,35]
   #<space>        | [35,35,35,35,10,35,32]
     <.>           | [35,35,35,35,10,35,32,35]
        #<newline> | [35,35,35,35,10,35,32,35,10]
<..                | [35,35,35,10,35,32,35,10,35,35,35]
   &@              | Print entire stack

35 = # ASCII value
10 = <newline> ASCII value
32 = <space> ASCII value

Output:
###
# #
###
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 21 bytes

```
.
$&$&$&¶$& $&¶$&$&$&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@6/HpaIGgoe2qagpQCgQ/P9fGQA)

Comment: It's shorter to match `$` and insert `$_` or `$\`` (saving two bytes)

Answer (score 0):

## [Befunge](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 26 bytes

```
~:::25*\:84*\:25*\::>:#,_@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge#@19nZWVlZKoVY2VhAiTALCs7K2WdeIf//40A)

Explanation

```
~::          Take input and put bottom row in stack (: is duplicate)
:25*\:84*\   Create second row (25* is 10 or newline, 84* is 32 or space)
:25*\::      Create top row
>:#,_@       Print out stack until the stack is empty

the \ after the numbers is to switch the stack around since you need the input on 
top of the stack to duplicate it
```

Answer (score 0):

## `bash`, <s>43</s> 38 bytes

```
read -sN1 x
echo "$x$x$x
$x $x
$x$x$x"
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 23 bytes

```scala
a=>a*3+s"\n$a $a\n"+a*3
```

Accepts and returns a `String`. The `s` before a string literal allows you to use `$`-prefixed variables in it, or even `${expressions}`. `*` repeats a `String`, like in Python.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/scala#y0/KSk0uUfBNzMxTSK0oSc1LKVZwLChQqOYqS8xRSLNS0AguKcrMS1ewtVOAsDQVbP8n2tolahlrFyvF5KkkKqgkxuQpaQMF/hcAFZRopGkoKStpanLV/gcA)

Answer (score 0):

### VBScript, 72 bytes

```
n=chr(10):msgbox replace("###"&n&"# #"&n&"###","#",wscript.arguments(0))
```

VBScript sucks ;-)

Answer (score 0):

## [Foo](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Foo), 40 bytes

```
&<character as ascii value>&3(-1<$c>)$c13<$c$c32$c$c13>&3(-1<$c>)
```

As Foo cannot take input, you should replace `<character as ascii value>` with the ASCII value of the character.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/foo#@69mbGqnZqyha2ijkmynqZJsaAxkqCQbG4FIQ2Mkuf//AQ)

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, SBCL, 50 bytes

```
(format t"~@?
~a ~:*~a
~@*~@?""~3@{~a~:*~}"(read))
```

### Explanation

```
format              ;printing function
~@?                 ;execute format string given as argument
~a ~:*~a            ;print current argument (will be result of (read))
                    ;then print space, go back one argument (to again use 
                    ;result of (read) and print it  
~@*~@?              ;go back to first argument, then execute format string 
                    ;given as this argument
"~3@{~a~:*~}"       ;loop three times printing argument number 2 
                    ;~:* makes it keep going back to argument number 2
(read)              ;take input
```

Ideas for improvement are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

## Excel VBA, 27 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from cell `[A1]` on the `Application.ActiveSheet` object and outputs a 'square' to the VBE immediate window.

```vba
a=[A1]:?a;a;a:?a" "a:?a;a;a
```

Answer (score 0):

## Swift, 54 bytes

```
var s=readLine()!,a=s+s+s+"\n";print(a+s+" "+s+"\n"+a)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Sinclair ZX80/ZX81 (without sanity check), ~55 Bytes (listing)

```
 1 INPUT A$
 2 PRINT A$;A$;A$
 3 PRINT A$;" ";A$
 4 PRINT A$;A$;A$
```

#### With sanity check (ZX80 with 8K ROM or ZX81)

```
 1 INPUT A$
 2 IF NOT LEN A$ OR LEN A$>1 THEN GOTO 1
 3 PRINT A$;A$;A$
 4 PRINT A$;" ";A$
 5 PRINT A$;A$;A$
```

Line two of the latter version makes sure that there is a single character entered. So in the first example, it is possible to enter nothing and simply press `NEW LINE`.

[image: The BASIC listing result with entry of asterisk]

Comment: This would use 52 bytes of program memory.

Comment: So my approximation is broadly correct? I keep forgetting to POKE the memory to see how much actual RAMs my ZX80/81 programs take up; it also depends on the ROM used in the ZX80. If it's the 'old ROM' then each numeric variable is a 16-bit signed integer only, taking two bytes, whereas with the 8K ROM upgrade that becomes a floating point number of 5 bytes in memories total.

Comment: Ah, well fortunately your program contains no numbers (at least, not the short version, which is what I counted). Also, I hope you `PEEK` to find out the actual usage, which would be `PRINT PEEK 16396 + 256 * PEEK 16397 - 16509`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was making a general point about all of my ZX80/ZX81 entries rather than something specific about this listing

Comment: I'm just amazed that you have a ZX80 with the 8K ROM upgrade. (I'm just marginally too young for that, having started with the ZX81.)

Comment: Well, of sorts; I have a Minstrel clone that you can buy which has a 4K/8K ROM. I have lots of ZX81s in various states and a Commodore PET (3032) as well as a VIC/VC 20, C64, C128, +4 etc... I used to write about this stuff for Micro Mart magazine and others but now I'm a software developer I thought it best to make software for these old machines. I currently have a Commodore PET game and some ZX80/ZX81 games ready to be released by Monument Microgames. I'll also be making some VIC-20 and C16 stuff soon.

Comment: Our first 'home computer' was the Texas TI99/4a which I think pre-dates the ZX80 even.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59910/discussion-between-shaun-bebbers-and-neil).

Answer (score 0):

## PowerShell, 26 Bytes

```
param($c)$c*3;"$c $c";$c*3
```

takes a char/length 1 string - then prints it 3 times, it twice with a separating space, and it 3 times again.

Answer (score 0):

## [braingasm](https://github.com/daniero/braingasm), 18 bytes

```
,...10..32..10....
```

Yeah... read a byte, print it three times, then print a newline (`10`), then the byte again, then a space (`32`), that byte again, another newline and that byte three more times...

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/documentation), <s>45</s> 44 bytes

-1 byte thanks to Laikoni

Naive approach

```
f s=putStrLn$s:s:s:'\n':s:' ':s:'\n':s:s:[s]
```

For some reason

```
f s=putStr$s:s:s:'\n':s:' ':s:'\n':s:s:[s]
```

won't output the last line on repl.it, but if it's still valid it shaves off 2 bits for a total of 42

And

```
f s=print$s:s:s:'\n':s:' ':s:'\n':s:s:[s]
```

will print the answer as "sss\ns s\nsss" instead of properly linebreaking. If that's valid it shaves off 3 bits for a total of 41

There is a solution with replace that's 42 bits long ... but that's without counting the bytes needed to import the necessary module. For reference:

```
import Data.String.Utils
f s=putStrLn$replace "." s "...\n. .\n..."
```

Comment: You can shorten `s:[]` to `[s]`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 23+1 = 24 bytes

Uses the `-n` flag for +1 byte.

```ruby
puts$_*3,$_+' '+$_,$_*3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#U1YsKk2qVNDN@19QWlKsEq9lrKMSr62uoK6tEq8D4v7/HwgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [OCaml](https://ocaml.org/), 53 bytes

```
let f c=String.map(function '#'->c|c->c)"###
# #
###"
```

It's pretty bad. OCaml does not even have a replace function

## Bash, 26 bytes

```
echo "$1$1$1
$1 $1
$1$1$1"
```

5 bytes less boring

Comment: Suggestion: Post you OCaml answer and Bash answers separately.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 34 bytes

```python
lambda n:3*n+'\n'+n+" "+n+'\n'+3*n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPylgrT1s9Jk9dO09bSUFJG8oBiv4vKMrMK1FI01B3UNf8DwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [UGL](https://repl.it/@_Nobody_/ugl-1-0-0), 23 Bytes

```
j"\n"++l*I3l++i" "il*i3
```

[try it online](http://hightechembellishedsecurity.five-nine.repl.run/) (write the code to stdin. you can also use the link at the top of the answer to try online, that accepts ctrl+v)

Equivalent Python code:

```
cur_inp = ""
def inp():
    global cur_inp
    cur_inp = input()
    return cur_inp
"\n".join([inp*3]+[cur_inp+" "+cur_inp]+[cur_inp*3])
```

Using Python's string multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 20 bytes

```
3.*3.*{1 1}' D!)\[un
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f/fWE8LiKoNFQxr1RVcFDVjokvz/v93BAA)

```
3.*       # Make a list of 3 instances     {A A A}
3.*       # Again                          {{A A A} {A A A} {A A A}}
{1 1}' D! # Set value at 1,1 to a space    {{A A A} {A   A} {A A A}}
)\[       # Concatenate each internal list {"AAA" "A A" "AAA"}
un        # Join array with newlines
```

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 23 bytes

```
495b2"1"x/r~'0' r~3coun
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f/fxNI0yUjJUKlCv6hO3UBdoajOODm/NO//f0cA)

Just for a bit of variety

```
495b2   # Read the number 495 as binary (111101111)
"1"x/r~ # Replace 1s with input char
'0' r~  # Replace 0 with space
3co     # Chunks of 3
un      # Separate by newlines
```

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 15 bytes

```apl
(' ',⍞)[⊤7 5 7]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qG@qp/@jtgkGXI862tP@a6grqOs86p2nGf2oa4m5gqmCeex/oMR/zjSuRC4uoGKgUnV1Li4gXxkA)

Indexes into a binary matrix.

Requires `⎕IO←0`(0-indexing)

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes

```
D¶?ðWṅ∞
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJEwrY/w7BX4bmF4oieIiwiIiwiYSJd)

Using the canvas builtin is the same byte count:

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes

```
3»«₁»ø∧
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCIzwrvCq+KCgcK7w7jiiKciLCIiLCJhIl0=)

Answer (score 0):

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/), 22 characters

```
*=*$0$0\n$0 $0\n$0$0$0
```

(Frustratingly inefficient. In Gema the `*` (and `?`) have order numbers, so in `***=***` each `*` on right side matches the `*` on left side with same order number. ☹)

Sample run:

```
bash-5.2$ echo -n 'M' | gema '*=*$0$0\n$0 $0\n$0$0$0'
MMM
M M
MMM
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/NTfz/X8tWS8VAxSAmT8VAAUKB4P//vgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/), 24 bytes

```
sub(/./,"&&&\n& &\n&&&")
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704sTx7wYKlpSVpuhY7ikuTNPT19HWU1NTUYvLUFECEmpqSJkQaqmrBQmUIAwA) or [try some more test cases.](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704sTx7wYKlpSVpuhY7ikuTNPT19HWU1NTUYvLUFECEmpqSJkQaqmrBem0uLS5dLj0uRy5lLgOuaIgwAA)

This is one byte shorter than [`$0=$0$0$0RS$0FS$0RS$0$0$0`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/198612/78410).

This is basically regex substitution that takes one char and puts it into the box shape. `sub` without the 3rd argument takes and modifies `$0` in-place. Since the substitution always succeeds, the `sub` call evaluates to true and the modified `$0` is printed (the default action).

`sub($0,...)` doesn't work because some chars don't form a valid regex, such as `[`.