# Visualise the Euclidean GCD

Tags: code-golf, math, ascii-art, number-theory

The [Euclidean GCD Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) is an algorithm that efficiently computes the GCD of two positive integers, by repeatedly subtracting the smaller number from the larger number until they become equal. It can be visualised as such:

We start with a MxN grid, where M and N are the numbers. In this example I'll use M=12, N=5:

```
       12
  ____________
 |
 |
5|
 |
 |
```

We then, going from the top left, remove a square with a side length of the smaller of the two values, 5, leaving a 7x5 rectangle. This is visualised by replacing the last column of the 5x5 square with a column of `|`s.

```
          7
  ____________
 |    |
 |    |
5|    |
 |    |
 |    |
```

We then remove another 5x5 square, leaving a 2x5 rectangle:

```
            2
  ____________
 |    |    |
 |    |    |
5|    |    |
 |    |    |
 |    |    |
```

Next, we remove two 2x2 squares, leaving a 2x1 rectangle. As these squares are added when the rectangle is taller than it is wide, their bottom rows are replaced with rows of `_`s.

```
            2
  ____________
 |    |    |
 |    |    |__
 |    |    |
 |    |    |__
1|    |    |
```

And finally, we remove a 1x1 square, leaving a 1x1 square, whose last and only column is replaced with a `|`. As this is a square, the two sides are equal, so the GCD of 12 and 5 is 1.

The final visualisation looks like this. Note that the numbers are not included, those were just visual indicators.

```
    |    |
    |    |__
    |    |
    |    |__
    |    ||
```

Here's a larger example for M=16, N=10. (I'm not going to go through all the steps here).

```
         |
         |
         |
         |
         |
         |______
         |   |
         |   |__
         |   |
         |   |
```

Note that, as gcd(16, 10) = 2, the algorithm ends with a 2x2 square.

Your challenge is to implement this visualisation, given two numbers M and N where M > N. Your output may have any amount of leading/trailing whitespace.

### Testcases

```
12, 5 ->
    |    |
    |    |__
    |    |
    |    |__
    |    ||

10, 16 ->
         |
         |
         |
         |
         |
         |______
         |   |
         |   |__
         |   |
         |   |
25, 18 ->
                 |       
                 |       
                 |       
                 |       
                 |       
                 |       
                 |_______
                 |       
                 |       
                 |       
                 |       
                 |       
                 |       
                 |_______
                 |   |   
                 |   |   
                 |   |___
                 |   ||| 

25, 10 ->
         |         |     
         |         |     
         |         |     
         |         |     
         |         |_____
         |         |     
         |         |     
         |         |     
         |         |     
         |         |     

34, 15 ->
              |              |    
              |              |    
              |              |    
              |              |____
              |              |    
              |              |    
              |              |    
              |              |____
              |              |    
              |              |    
              |              |    
              |              |____
              |              |  |_
              |              |  |_
              |              |  | 

89, 55 ->
                                                      |                                  
                                                      |                                  
                                                      |                                  
                                                      |                                  
                                                      |                                  
                                                      |                                  
                                                      |                                  
                                                      |                                  
                                                      |                                  
                                                      |                                  
                                                      |                                  
                                                      |                                  
                                                      |                                  
                                                      |                                  
                                                      |                                  
                                                      |                                  
                                                      |                                  
                                                      |                                  
                                                      |                                  
                                                      |                                  
                                                      |                                  
                                                      |                                  
                                                      |                                  
                                                      |                                  
                                                      |                                  
                                                      |                                  
                                                      |                                  
                                                      |                                  
                                                      |                                  
                                                      |                                  
                                                      |                                  
                                                      |                                  
                                                      |                                  
                                                      |__________________________________
                                                      |                    |             
                                                      |                    |             
                                                      |                    |             
                                                      |                    |             
                                                      |                    |             
                                                      |                    |             
                                                      |                    |             
                                                      |                    |             
                                                      |                    |             
                                                      |                    |             
                                                      |                    |             
                                                      |                    |             
                                                      |                    |_____________
                                                      |                    |       |     
                                                      |                    |       |     
                                                      |                    |       |     
                                                      |                    |       |     
                                                      |                    |       |_____
                                                      |                    |       |  |  
                                                      |                    |       |  |__
                                                      |                    |       |  ||
```

Comment: Quite similar: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/119714/15469

Comment: @Jonah I would call this a dupe of that, though they might be different enough to stay separate.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 43 bytes

```
ＮθＮηＢθη Ｗ⁻θη¿›θη«≧⁻ηθＭ⊖η→Ｐ↓η→»«≧⁻θηＭ⊖θ↓⟦×_θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY5BC4IwGIbP@is@PE2wQ0EXOxVCdDAiukWE2ZcbzKnb1CD67ctNCi8d373f@zzLaSbzKuPG7ETd6n1b3lCSJlz500yHvKmepImARhBAMOSeMo5AUiZa5YowBPYAspWYacsYn16@l2b1WilWiCMrqB4XDmQ1Xlp1SBLMJZYoNN4HWQSxO3V1yzWrJROaxEnVC0v9rn5Xb0Cu8L@rma6mrsa6LNa2B2c5n1iJigTXwH7wYunGzBewNLOOfwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＮθＮη
```

Input `M` and `N`.

```
Ｂθη
```

Draw an `M×N` box. This solves two problems; firstly, in case one value divides the other, as I assume I'm not allowed `-N` trailing white space; secondly, in case `M>N`, as I assume I'm not allowed `1-N` leading white space.

```
Ｗ⁻θη
```

Repeat until `M=N`.

```
¿›θη«
```

If `M>N`, then:

```
≧⁻ηθ
```

Subtract `N` from `M`.

```
Ｍ⊖η→
```

Move `N-1` to the right.

```
Ｐ↓η
```

Draw `N` `|`s downwards.

```
→
```

Move to the right.

```
»«
```

Otherwise, if `N>M`:

```
≧⁻θη
```

Subtract `M` from `N`.

```
Ｍ⊖θ↓
```

Move `M-1` down.

```
⟦×_θ
```

Draw `M` `_`s and move down.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 128 bytes

```javascript
x=>h=(y,i=x,j=y)=>j?(g=(x,y)=>i?y-j+1|x<i?x-i+1|y<j?x>y?g(x-y,y):x<y?g(x,y-x):' ':'|':'_':`
`)(x,y)+(i?h(y,i-1,j):h(y,x,j-1)):''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3NCoMwEITvfYresovZQgr9IbjmUapI1QSppRbZgO@eRo89DHwzDDOhWZq5/fj3l5Z76jgJVwND1J5FB47IVXDQM4je2LtIoTCrlN4J@UyxDE6q6HoQirljpdyNjiRo1VFZtWY9lK0PNe4zBXg3bBdkdEC7Yf4ig7mvUju95ml8nsaphw7MGeGCePhLbwjXnKYf)